# Using Powershell, how can i count the occurrence of each element in an array?

Tags: arrays, powershell, scripting

If I have an array:

> 1 1 1 2 2 3 4 4 4 4 5 5

How can I use Powershell to tell me how many of each element there are in that array?

To be a little more clear, I should have a separate count for each array element:

> **Element:Count**
>
> 1:3
>
> 2:2
>
> 3:1
>
> 4:4
>
> 5:2

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use the `Group-Object` cmdlet:

```
PS> 1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4,4,5,5 | group

Count Name                      Group
----- ----                      -----
    3 1                         {1, 1, 1}
    2 2                         {2, 2}
    1 3                         {3}
    4 4                         {4, 4, 4, 4}
    2 5                         {5, 5}
```

If you want a hashtable for the items and their counts you just need a little `ForEach-Object` after it:

```
$array | group | % { $h = @{} } { $h[$_.Name] = $_.Count } { $h }
```

Comment: Thanks for this. What would be an elegant way to derive the `mode` (most frequently occurring value) of the original array? That is, given the OP's array `1 1 1 2 2 3 4 4 4 4 5 5`, I need to return `4`.

Comment: @IfediOkonkwo: `1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4,4,5,5 | group -NoElement | sort Count | select -last 1 -expandProperty Name`. A bit long, but each part of that pipeline does a single thing and composes well. Another option would be to separate getting the value and picking the last one with `... | group -NoElement | sort Count | % Name | select -last 1`.

Comment: @Joey: thanks a million. Before noticing your response, I'd cobbled something together, that worked, though more unwieldy than yours: `$hash = $Array | group | % { $h = @{} } { $h[$_.Name] = $_.Count } { $h };
 $mode = $hash.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object -Property Value -Descending | Select-Object -First 1`

Comment: @mklement0: I completely agree with you. But then, it's only human that laziness sometimes gets the better of you. Hopefully, google can still lead searchers to this very thread ;)

Comment: @IfediOkonkwo: Alternatively, we can [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58738500/45375). Note that your solution doesn't handle the case where _multiple_ values occur most frequently.

Comment: Wow! You put me to shame by that elaborate self-answered effort! Well done and +1 for both question and answer.

Answer (score 7):

You can adjust the output and format it as you like:

```
PS> $ht= 1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4,4,5,5 | Group-Object -AsHashTable -AsString
PS> $ht

Name                           Value
----                           -----
2                              {2, 2}
4                              {4, 4, 4, 4}
5                              {5, 5}
1                              {1, 1, 1}
3                              {3}


PS> $ht['1']
1
1
1
```

Comment: They wanted the counts, though. Thus `-AsHashTable` is of little help.

Comment: `$ht['#'].count`, in `System.Collections.Hashtable` it contains a method called `count`

Answer (score 7):

[Joey's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12640991/45375) provides the crucial pointer: **use the [`Group-Object` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object) to group input objects by equality.**
(To group them by one ore more of their *property values* instead, use `-Property`).

`Group-Object` outputs [`[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GroupInfo]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.commands.groupinfo) objects that each represent a *group* of equal input objects, whose notable properties are:

- `.Values` ... the value(s) that define the group, as a `[System.Collections.ArrayList]` instance (which has just *1* element in the case at hand, since the input objects *as a whole* are used to form the groups).
- `.Count` ... the count of objects in that group.

If, as in this case, there is no need to collect the individual group members as part of each group, 
`-NoElement` can be used for efficiency.

You're free to further process the group objects as needed; to get the specific output format stipulated in your question, you can use `Select-Object` with a [calculated property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39861920/45375).

To put it all together:

```
PS> 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5 | Group-Object -NoElement |
      Select-Object @{ n='Element:Count'; e={ '{0}:{1}' -f $_.Values[0], $_.Count } }

Element:Count
-------------
1:3
2:2
3:1
4:4
5:2
```