# Create objects with custom properties containing derived filesystem path information and export them to a CSV - calculated properties

Tags: powershell, path, export-to-csv, select-object

<sup>Editor's note:

The gist of this question is:

* How do I add custom properties to objects output by `Get-ChildItem` that contain derived path information, namely the parent folder path (as `Folder` and name (as `Foldername`)?

* How do I export the resulting objects to a CSV file?</sup>

Currently have a script running that I took from StackOverflow and modified for my own use. The purpose of the script is to look at a directory, grab file names, then export them to a directory as a .csv file.

I was able to modify the script to pull through just the file name as originally it only pulled through the `path, user` etc. Was able to do this by adding `,Name`. For some reason I can't get the script to pull through the parent folder it's in, also wanting the parents parent folder.

I believe this part of the code is what I am having most trouble with. Upon the `select` I was able to add `,Name` but adding `,folder` or `,foldername` after the `select` doesn't pull through properly.

```
ForEach-Object {$_ | Add-Member -Name "Owner" -MemberType NoteProperty -Value (Get-Acl $_.FullName).Owner -PassThru} | 
 Sort-Object fullname | 
  Select FullName,CreationTime,LastWriteTime,Owner,Name,Folder,Foldername
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[System.IO.FileInfo]` instances returned by `Get-ChildItem` for files do not have `Folder` or `FolderName` properties.

`Get-ChildItem -File $HOME\Desktop | Get-Member`, for instance, will show you the available properties, and will show you that the desired information can be *derived* from the `PSPath` and `PSParentPath` properties.

**[`Select-Object`](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849895.aspx) allows *hashtable*-based property definitions**, so-called **[*calculated properties*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties)**, which **allow you to *rename* and/or *transform* properties and/or *add custom properties*** derived from other property values by way of a script block.

Note: **You can also use calculated properties with the `Format-Table` and `Format-List` cmdlets** for creating output for *display* only (as well as with other cmdlets - see the linked help topic).

A simplified example of what you're looking for (includes output to a CSV file):

```
Get-ChildItem $HOME\Desktop | Select-Object Name,
  @{ Name = 'Folder'; Expression = { Convert-Path $_.PSParentPath } },
  @{ Name = 'Foldername'; Expression = { ($_.PSPath -split '\\')[-2] } } |
    Export-Csv Out.csv -Encoding Utf8 -NoTypeInformation
```

<sup>Note that, alternatively, you could add `Folder` and `FolderName` properties to the input objects via `Add-Member`, as you did with the `Owner` property in your question.</sup>

**Explanation**:

<sup>Note that you can get more detailed information about any of the commands mentioned by running `Get-Help <command-name> -Full`; add `-online` to view the help topic in a browser; to learn more about the `-split` operator, run `Get-Help about_split`; to learn about PowerShell's help system in general, run `Get-Help Get-Help -online`.</sup>

- Each **`@{ ... }`** construct passed to `Select-Object` is a **[hash table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) that defines a calculated property** to attach to each output object:

  - The hash table **must have two entries**:

    - **`Name` *or* `Label`**, which defines the **property's *name***; for brevity, you may use a (case-insensitive) prefix of the key name, such as just `n` or `l`.
    - **`Expression`**, which defines the **property's *value***; again, a (case-insensitive) prefix of the key name works too, such as just `e`.

      - The expression can be a mere property *name* (a string), in case you simply want to *rename* an input property, but is more typically a *script block* (`{ ... }`), which is a piece of code that gets executed for each input object, and whose output becomes the value of the property being defined; inside that script block, automatic variable `$_` (or `$PSItem`) refers to the input object at hand.
- **Definition of the `Folder` property:** `Convert-Path $_.PSParentPath` converts the fully qualified PowerShell path that the `PSParentPath` property contains - which includes a prefix identifying the drive provider - to a regular filesystem path; e.g., `Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Users\jdoe\Desktop` -> `C:\Users\jdoe\Desktop`.
- **Definition of the `Foldername` property:** `($_.PSPath -split '\\')[-2]` splits the full path into components by path separator `\`, and then accesses the next-to-last component (`-2`), which is the parent folder name; e.g., `C:\Users\jdoe\Desktop\file.txt` -> `Desktop`

  - `'\\'` must be used to represent `\`, because `-split`'s 1st RHS operand is a *regular expression*, where `\` has special meaning and must therefore be doubled to be taken as a literal.
  - If you wanted to support `/` as the path separator as well for cross-platform support, you'd use `($_.PSPath -split '[\\/]')[-2]`.
- **`Export-Csv`** exports the objects output by `Select-Object` to CSV `Out.csv`, where the input objects' property names become the header row, and the property values the data rows.

  - `-Encoding Utf8`, required in *Windows PowerShell* only (PowerShell (Core) 7+ now fortunately consistently uses BOM-less UTF-8), ensures that non-ASCII characters are properly encoded; by default, `Export-Csv` uses ASCII encoding and simply replaces non-ASCII characters, such as foreign letters, with *verbatim* `?` characters, resulting in loss of information; note that `-Encoding Utf8` in Windows PowerShell *invariably* creates UTF-8 files *with a BOM*.
  - `-NoTypeInformation`, again required in *Windows PowerShell* only, suppresses a line that `Export-Csv` by defaults adds as the first line of the output file, which contains the full type name (class name) of the input objects (e.g., `#TYPE System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject`; this is meant to facilitate later reconversion into objects).