# How to find the sum of two columns in PowerShell?

Tags: json, powershell

I'm attempting to create a PowerShell script that queries a website using an API that responds with JSON data.  I then want to get the sum of two columns that are selected. I'm new to PowerShell scripting and this seems simple but I can't find the answer.  Hoping someone can help.

An example of the returned JSON from the API:

```
{"getuserbalance":{"version":"1.0.0","runtime":4.3599605560303,"data":{"confirmed":0.05500048,"unconfirmed":0.00472891,"orphaned":0}}}
```

This is what I have so far:

```
$balance = 'www.example.com/index.php?page=api&action=getuserbalance'
Invoke-WebRequest $balance |
ConvertFrom-Json |
Select -expand getuserbalance |
select -expand data |
select confirmed, unconfirmed
```

Which gives me:

```
 confirmed unconfirmed
 --------- -----------
 0.05500048  0.00472891
```

Unsure about how to add these two together. I looked at the Measure-Object cmdlet but didn't see a way to sum two columns.

Your help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Dragnan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to **output only the sum itself**, use the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet:

```
[pscustomobject] @{ name = 'foo'; confirmed = 1; unconfirmed = 2 } | 
  ForEach-Object { $_.confirmed + $_.unconfirmed }
```

This yields:

```
3
```

The script block (`{ ... }`) passed to `ForEach-Object` is invoked for every input object, and automatic variable `$_` inside the script block refers to the input object at hand.

To assign the result to a variable, simply place `$sum =` before the pipeline; with multiple input objects, `$sum` will receive an *array* of values.

Run [`Get-Help ForEach-Object`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) to learn more.

---

If you want to ***add a column* containing the sum**, use a *calculated property*:

```
[pscustomobject] @{ name = 'foo'; confirmed = 1; unconfirmed = 2 } | 
  Select-Object confirmed, unconfirmed, @{ n='combined'; e={ $_.confirmed + $_.unconfirmed } }
```

This yields:

```
confirmed unconfirmed combined
--------- ----------- --------
        1           2        3
```

To learn more about calculated properties, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39861920/45375) of mine.