# adding variable to format list output

Tags: powershell

I have a question about adding a variable to the output of format-list.  When I run the command:

`get-CsAdUser | Format-List DisplayName, Enabled`

I get the output

**DisplayName : user01

Enabled : True**

**DisplayName : user02

Enabled : False**

I have a variable `$var1 = "folder one"`  that I need to add to the output so it looks like :

**DisplayName : user01

Enabled : True

folder one**

**DisplayName : user02

Enabled : False

folder one**

Anyone have an idea on how to do this?  Thanks

Comment: Do you need it exactly like in your question or it can be `Folder: folder one` instead of just `folder one`?

Comment: `Folder: folder one` will work

Comment: `get-CsAdUser | Format-List DisplayName, Enabled, @{ Label = 'Folder'; Expression = { $var1 } }`

Comment: OK that worked thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a meta note:

[PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral), as he often does, has provided an effective answer in a *comment*.

However, it is preferable to have an actual answer *post* that can be marked as *accepted* so as to signal to future readers what solution truly solved the OP's problem.

---

As PetSerAl notes:

```
get-CsAdUser | Format-List DisplayName, Enabled, @{Label = 'Folder'; Expression = {$var1}}
```

adds a third property to each input object's output that prints the value of variable `$var1` as an *ad-hoc, calculated* property named `Folder`, following the preexisting `DisplayName` and `Enabled` properties.

The `@{ Label = ...; Expression = ... }` part of the command is a PowerShell hashtable literal that is an instance of a **calculated property**, which you can use with `Select-Object`, `Format-Table`, and `Format-List`, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39861920/45375) of mine.