# Semicolon-delimited string to list or object

Tags: powershell

I'm sure this is quite easy but I can't find a way to format a semicolon-delimited string as a list or object, with as generic method as possible.

Running the command displays the following:

```
PS> Get-childitem -path Env:\Path

Name                           Value
----                           -----
Path                           Value1;Value2;Value3 etc...
```

Expected result is:

```
Name                               Value
----                               ----
Path                               Value1
Path                               Value2
Path                               Value3
```

Comment: Not quite what you were after but produces an array of the values: `(Get-ChildItem -Path Env:\Path | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value) -split ";"`

Answer (score 2):

You can split the value and use ex. `Select-Object` with calculated properties to add the Name-property.

```
$env:Path.Split(';',[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries) | Select-Object @{n="Name";e={"Path"}}, @{n="Value";e={$_}}
```

Or using cmdlet

```
(Get-Item Env:\Path | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value).Split(';',[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries) |
Select-Object @{n="Name";e={"Path"}}, @{n="Value";e={$_}}
```

If you want to support multiple variables:

```
Get-ChildItem Env:\Path | ForEach-Object {
    $name = $_.Name
    $_.Value -split ';' | Where-Object { $_ } | Select-Object @{n="Name";e={$name}}, @{n="Value";e={$_}}
}
```

Output:

```
Name Value
---- -----
Path C:\WINDOWS\system32
Path C:\WINDOWS
Path C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
Path C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
....
```

(I use `RemoveEmptyEntries` and `Where-Object { $_ }` to avoid empty entries as I had a trailing `;` in my own Path-variable)

Answer (score 1):

To get the exact output you want:

```bash
$env:Path -split ';' -ne '' |
  Select-Object @{ n = 'Name'; e = { 'Path '} }, @{ n = 'Value'; e = { $_ } }
```

- `$env:Path -split ';'` splits the value of `$env:Path` (the more efficient equivalent of `Get-Item env:\Path`) into an array of strings by separatory `;`.
- `-ne ''` removes *empty* entries from the resulting array.
- The `Select-Object` command constructs a 2-property object for each array entry that by default displays as a *table*:

  - The `@{ ... }` arguments are [*calculated properties*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties) that define the `.Name` and `.Value` properties for the output object, using a hashtable format that is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39861920/45375).

Answer (score 0):

Following code snippet may be useful:

```
("Name          ->      Value`r`n--------------------------------------------------");(Get-ChildItem -Path Env:\Path | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value) -split ";" | foreach {"Path   ->   " + $_}
```

It will produce following output:

```
Name          ->      Value
--------------------------------------------------
Path   ->   C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath
Path   ->   C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\
Path   ->   C:\WINDOWS\system32
Path   ->   C:\WINDOWS
Path   ->   C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
```