# How do I group and sum CSV rows by shared column value?

Tags: windows, powershell, csv, grouping

I'm new with powershell and I am currently stuck with an issue.

I import a CSV file with 2 columns (ServerName, and Size)
like this :

```
Server | Size
-------------
SRV1   | 140

SRV2   | 120

SRV1   | 100

SRV1   | 140

SRV2   | 200
```

I want to add all Size values for each server, for example:

```
SRV2 = 120+200
SRV1 = 140+100+140
```

I have no idea how to do it.
I tried with a for loop, but the operation is done for each line, so my results are false.
Could anyone help me ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

- the [`Group-Object` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object) to group the CSV rows by server name (`Server`)
- then use [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) to construct a single output object *per group*,
- containing the server name and the *sum* of all the associated rows' `Size` values, obtained via a [calculated property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39861920/45375) that uses the [`Measure-Object` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/measure-object):

```
Import-Csv file.csv | Group-Object Server | 
  Select-Object Name, @{ n='Size'; e={ ($_.Group | Measure-Object Size -Sum).Sum } }
```

<sup>If you want the first output column to be named `Server`, replace `Name` with `@{ n='Server'; e='Name' }`</sup>

With your sample data, the above yields:

```
Name Size
---- ----
SRV1  380
SRV2  320
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how you could do it:

```
$Data = Import-Csv -Path "yourfilepath" -Delimiter ";"

$SortedData = $Data | Group {$_.server}
$Hashtable = @{}
$SortedData.group | ForEach-Object {
    if ($Hashtable.Contains($_.server)) {
        $Hashtable[$_.server] += ",$($_.size)"
    } else {
        $Hashtable.Add($_.server,$_.size)
    }
}
```

You need to change your delimiter in your case

Comment: Thanks for you answer.
If my CSV contains more than 2 differents servers, will it still work ? 
Because in my example i have 2 servers, but in fact , it can be 3 or 4.

Comment: it should work with any amount of servers, please mark the answer as solution when it solved your problem.

Comment: I think the intent is to actually _sum_ the values (add them up and report the sum), not to generate a string representation of the addition operation. Also note that by using a hashtable the order of the entries is not guaranteed.