# Replace Arrows for SideIndicator in Compare-Object

Tags: powershell, compareobject

Can I change the output for SideIndicators as a result of `Compare-Object` to something more user friendly for standard users?

I have a script that compares the folder of a 2017 version of our software and the current 2018 version.

```
$var1 = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path C:\software18\bin
$var2 = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path C:\software17\bin
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $var1 -DifferenceObject $var2 > C:\diff.txt
```

The output looks like this:

```
InputObject           SideIndicator
-----------           -------------
thing.dll                 =>
stuff.dll                 <=
software.exe              <=
```

The report is given to testers and it would be cleaner for them if I could change the SideIndicators into text.

My desired output:

```
InputObject           SideIndicator
-----------           -------------
thing.dll                Not in 18
stuff.dll                Not in 17
software.exe             Not in 17
```

Or something similiar where they can get the gist of it without having to know which is the reference/difference object.

I have an initial idea but searching for something similar doesn't yield many results. Don't know if I have to do an `if` loop or I can replace the brackets in PS. Still new to PS so I greatly appreciate the help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could loop over each object make a conditional for each side indicator:

```
$var1 = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path C:\software18\bin
$var2 = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path C:\software17\bin
(Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $var1 -DifferenceObject $var2 -PassThru |
    ForEach-Object {
        if ($_.SideIndicator -eq '=>') {
            $_.SideIndicator = 'Not in 18'
        } elseif ($_.SideIndicator -eq '<=')  {
            $_.SideIndicator = 'Not in 17'
        }
        $_
    }) > C:\diff.txt
```

Or you could just regex replace the strings in one step:

```
$var1 = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path C:\software18\bin
$var2 = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path C:\software17\bin
(Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $var1 -DifferenceObject $var2 -PassThru |
    ForEach-Object {
        $_.SideIndicator = $_.SideIndicator -replace '=>','Not in 18' -replace '<=','Not in 17'
        $_
    }) > C:\diff.txt
```

Comment: Tried both and my output was different. When I keep the `PassThru` parameters, the entire output was different (mode, last write).

Also, it would not write to the txt file. I moved the write to into the last parenthesis but outsid the curly braces and that seemed to have worked. Thank!

Answer (score 3):

When storing the Reference/Difference sources into a variable instead of directly expanding you can replace the sideindicator with the path.

Based on BenHs answer:

```
$Ref = "C:\software18\bin"
$Dif = "C:\software17\bin"
(Compare-Object -Ref (ls -r $Ref) -Dif (ls -r $Dif)|
    ForEach-Object {
        if ($_.SideIndicator -eq '=>') {
            $_.SideIndicator = "Not in $Ref"
        } elseif ($_.SideIndicator -eq '<=')  {
            $_.SideIndicator = "Not in $Dif"
        }
        $_
    }
) > C:\diff.txt
```

Simulated output:

```
InputObject           SideIndicator
-----------           -------------
thing.dll             Not in C:\software18\bin
stuff.dll             Not in C:\software17\bin
software.exe          Not in C:\software17\bin
```

Answer (score 2):

A long time ago, I wrote a script that uses compare-object to compare installed hotfixes across several machines in a cluster. http://get-powershell.com/post/2009/08/28/Comparing-Installed-Hotfixes-on-Servers.aspx

What I did was use a switch statement for different conditions of SideIndicator.

```
$comparedHotfixes = compare-object $server2HotFix $server1HotFix -IncludeEqual 

$result = @(); 

foreach ($c in $comparedHotfixes) { 
    $kbinfo = "" | select KB,$server1,$server2 
    $kbinfo.KB = $c.InputObject.HotfixId 
    switch ($c.SideIndicator) 
    { 
    "==" { 
            write-host -ForegroundColor Green "Both servers have $($c.InputObject.HotfixId)" 
            $kbinfo.($server1) = $true 
            $kbinfo.($server2) = $true 
            $result += $kbinfo 
         } 

    "=>" { 
            write-host -ForegroundColor Yellow "$server1 has $($c.InputObject.HotfixId) but $server2 doesn't" 
            $kbinfo.($server1) = $true 
            $kbinfo.($server2) = $false 
            $result += $kbinfo 
          } 

    "<="  { 
            write-host -ForegroundColor Magenta "$server2 has $($c.InputObject.HotfixId) but $server1 doesn't" 
            $kbinfo.($server1) = $false 
            $kbinfo.($server2) = $true 
            $result += $kbinfo 
          } 
    } # End Switch 
  } # End foreach
```

Answer (score 2):

A concise solution using `Select-Object` with a [calculated property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39861920/45375):

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $var1 -DifferenceObject $var2 |
  Select-Object InputObject, @{ 
   n='SideIndicator';
   e={ @{ '<=' = 'Not in 18'; '=>' = 'Not in 17' }[$_.SideIndicator] }
  } > C:\diff.txt
```