# Powershell piping an array of strings to ConvertTo-Html

Tags: html, powershell, calculated-field

For testing purposes (before I apply on my big code) I decided to pipe an array of string to convertTo-html hoping to create some kind of table displaying my array.

```
[String]$servers= @('GT544', 'HT54765', 'J4356', 'SW5654', 'JY67432')
psedit "C:\Users\karljoey.chami\Desktop\Htmltesting\Red.css"
$file = "C:\Users\karljoey.chami\Desktop\Htmltesting\Result.html"
$servers | ConvertTo-Html 
-Title "Servers in a table" -CssUri "C:\Users\karljoey.chami\Desktop\Htmltesting\Red.css" 
-pre "<h>The servers are</h>" | Out-file $file 
Invoke-Item $file
```

The problem is my array of string is being piped as the number of characters the array contains instead of the elements themselves.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$servers= 'GT544', 'HT54765', 'J4356', 'SW5654', 'JY67432'
$servers | ConvertTo-Html -Property @{ l='Name'; e={ $_ } }
```

<sup>Note: As [EBGreen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1358/ebgreen) observes, the `$servers` variable shouldn't be type-constrained as `[string] $servers = ...`, because that converts the array of strings to a *single* string. There is no strict need to type-constrain in this case, but you could use `[string[]] $servers = ...`</sup>

`ConvertTo-Html` by default enumerates all *properties* of the input objects, and in the case of `[string]` instances that is only the `.Length` property.

Therefore you need to use a *calculated property* that *wraps* your strings, which is what
`@{ l='Name'; e={ $_ } }` does; the `l` entry gives your property a *name* (will be used in the table header), and `e` entry defines its *value* via a script block (`{ ... }`), which in this case is simply the input string itself (`$_`).

<sup>For more on calculated properties, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39861920/45375) of mine, but note that `ConvertTo-Html` curiously only supports the `l` / `label` key for naming the property (not also `n` / `name`).

Also, passing calculated properties is [currently broken altogether in PowerShell *Core*, as of v6.1.0-preview.2](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6993)</sup>

The above yields:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>HTML TABLE</title>
</head><body>
<table>
<colgroup><col/></colgroup>
<tr><th>Name</th></tr>
<tr><td>GT544</td></tr>
<tr><td>HT54765</td></tr>
<tr><td>J4356</td></tr>
<tr><td>SW5654</td></tr>
<tr><td>JY67432</td></tr>
</table>
</body></html>
```

---

To put it all together:

```
$servers = 'GT544', 'HT54765', 'J4356', 'SW5654', 'JY67432'
$file = "C:\Users\karljoey.chami\Desktop\Htmltesting\Result.html"

$servers | ConvertTo-Html -Property @{ l='Name'; e={ $_ } } -Title "Servers in a table" `
  -CssUri "C:\Users\karljoey.chami\Desktop\Htmltesting\Red.css" `
  -pre "<h>The servers are</h>" | Out-file $file  

Invoke-Item $file
```