# Import list of users - Export List of users and Groups

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Is there any way I can import a list of users, get their groups in AD and export the list?

```
Import-Csv C:\Users.csv |
  % {Get-AdUser -filter "displayname -eq '$($_.username)'"} |
    Get-ADprincipalGroupMembership |
      Select samaccountname, name |
        Export-csv -path C:\UserPermiss.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

File example:

```
username
Jon Jo
Steve Price
Alan Partridge
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PSv4+ you can leverage the `-PipelineVariable` / `-pv` common parameter to make the output of an earlier pipeline stage available to script blocks used in later pipeline stages:

```
Import-Csv C:\Users.csv |
  ForEach-Object -pv user { Get-AdUser -filter "displayname -eq '$($_.username)'"} |
    Get-ADprincipalGroupMembership |
      Select-Object @{ n = 'samaccountname'; e = { $user.samaccountname } }, name |
        Export-csv -path C:\UserPermiss.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Using `-pv user` makes the AD user output by `Get-AdUser` available as variable `$user` in the `Select-Object` stage, where it is referenced in the script block of [calculated property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39861920/45375) `samaccountname`, pairing the name of the AD user at hand with the name of each AD group they are a member of.

The resulting CSV file would look something like this:

```
"samaccountname","name"
"jjo","group1"
"jjo","group2"
"sprice","group1"
"sprice","group3"
"sprice","group4"
# ...
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `memberof` property and then join the array of groups inside a [calculated property](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2017/01/19/using-powershell-calculated-properties.aspx).

```
Import-Csv C:\Users.csv | 
    ForEach-Object{
        Get-AdUser -Filter "displayname -eq '$($_.username)'" -Properties memberof
    } |
    Select-Object samaccountname, name, @{n='memberof';e={$_.memberof -join ';'}} |
    Export-Csv -Path C:\UserPermiss.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Hi BenH, 

Thanks for that, would it be possible to pull back just the group name? (and username)

Comment: @BenH How come this code is skipping some of my users and how can i use -Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity username