# Include unc path in file size output from powershell

Tags: powershell, output, unc

I'm very new to powershell. I have a txt file with a subset of UNC paths to directories that i need to determine the size of each of them. I've come up with the following which is working as intended but i have a couple of problems.

```
FUNCTION FileSize
{$DB = Get-Content 'C:\path\path\path\path\paths2.txt'
foreach ($Data in $DB) 
{"{0:N2} GB" -f ((Get-ChildItem "$Data" -Recurse | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum -ErrorAction Stop).Sum / 1GB)}}
```

I need to add into this the ability to see the UNC path that the size reading belongs too and f i could also output the results to a txt file that would beneficial too. All attempts so far have been futile.

Thanks,
Allan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you have the UNC path information stored in `$Data`, so you could add it in front of your output string. The save the output of the whole loop in a variable and you can export it by piping to `Out-File`, `Add-Content`, or `Set-Content`.

```
function FileSize {
    $DB = Get-Content 'C:\path\path\path\path\paths2.txt'
    $Sizes = foreach ($Data in $DB) {
        "$Data : {0:N2} GB" -f ((Get-ChildItem "$Data" -Recurse | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum -ErrorAction Stop).Sum / 1GB)
    }
    $Sizes | Out-File 'C:\path\path\path\path\out.txt'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[BenH's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50956243/45375) provides an effective solution that performs the output formatting directly inside the `FileSize` function.

Alternatively, for more flexibility, **consider refactoring your approach** so as to **separate the aspects of *data gathering* and *output formatting***:

First, modify your function:

- to accept the file containing the target paths as a *parameter*
- to output *custom* objects that have a `.Path` property containing the file path at hand, `.Size` property containing the aggregate size as a *number* (type `[double]`.

```
Function FileSize {
  param(
    [string] $PathsFile
  )
  foreach ($path in Get-Content $PathsFile) {
    [pscustomobject] @{
      Path = $path
      Size = (Get-ChildItem -File $path -Recurse | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum -ErrorAction Stop).Sum
    }
  }
}
```

The data-only output of the function then lets you decide *later* how to format the data and where to save it:

Using BenH's approach in a `ForEach-Object` call:

```
 FileSize 'C:\path\path\path\path\paths2.txt' |
   ForEach-Object { '{0} : {1:N2} GB' -f $_.Path, ($_.Size/1GB) }
```

You can simply append `> out.txt`, for instance, to save the output in a file; alternatively, piping to `Out-File` or `Set-Content` allows you to control the output file's character encoding with the `-Encoding` parameter.

To produce friendly tabular output for *display*, you can pipe to `Format-Table` using a [calculated property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39861920/45375):

```
 FileSize 'C:\path\path\path\path\paths2.txt' |
   Format-Table Path, @{ n='Size'; e={ '{0:N2} GB' -f ($_.Size/1GB) } }
```

Finally, for further *programmatic* processing, you can pipe `FileSize` output to export cmdlets such as `Export-Csv` and `Export-CliXml` or even conversion cmdlets such as `ConvertTo-Json`.

Comment: @phemor: I've rewritten the answer to focus more on the separation of data and formatting, so I'm no longer using `Select-Object`. While I still have no explanation for your symptom, I suspect the new solution will make it go away.