# Doing math on values in CSV Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, time

I have a CSV that contains a Scheduled Time (of day) but the value is in milliseconds from the start of day and I need to convert the values to time of day (0:HH:mm:ss,fff). This is how the CSV looks:

```
"Log Date","Scheduled Time","Category","Cart #","Scheduled Title","Actual Title","Start Date","End Date","Scheduled Length","Actual Length"
"7/18/2018 12:00:00 AM","22439181","DCM","3172","BONCHE URBANO DIGITAL 201","BONCHE URBANO COMERCIAL JUN 23","12/31/1969 7:00:00 PM","12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM","30","33"
"7/18/2018 12:00:00 AM","45750000","DCM","3172","BONCHE URBANO DIGITAL 201","BONCHE URBANO COMERCIAL JUN 23","12/31/1969 7:00:00 PM","12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM","30","33"
```

I have this and when I input the time into this, it works:

```
("{0:HH:mm:ss,fff}" -f ([datetime]([timespan]::fromseconds($time / 1000)).Ticks))
```

How can I use that to replace all the values in a CSV? I have this so far, but it doesn't work and I'm not great with Powershell to begin with.

```
Import-Csv .\Values.csv | 
ForEach-Object {
$time = $_.'Scheduled Time'
$_.'Scheduled Time' = ("{0:HH:mm:ss,fff}" -f ([datetime]([timespan]::fromseconds($time / 1000)).Ticks));$_
} | 
Export-Csv '.\Values.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Use [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-6) and an property expression like: `@{Name="Scheduled Time"; Expression = {("{0:HH:mm:ss,fff}" -f ([datetime]([timespan]::fromseconds($time / 1000)).Ticks))}}`

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[iRon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1701026/iron) has provided the crucial pointer in a comment on the question: **pipe the `Import-Csv` output to a `Select-Object` call, which enables selective *transformation* of the input objects' properties via [calculated properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39861920/45375)**.

Since you want to preserve the other properties as-is, while presumably performing the transformation without changing the property order, **you must explicitly enumerate *all* output properties**, which is perhaps easier to do by constructing an array up front.

```
# Define the property names to extract from the imported rows,
# interspersed with the calculcated property to transfrom the 'Scheduled Time'
# column values:
$properties = 
  'Log Date',
  @{ 
     n='Scheduled Time'
     e={ '{0:HH:mm:ss,fff}' -f [datetime] ([timespan]::FromTicks([long] $_.'Scheduled Time' * 10000)).Ticks } 
  },
  'Category',
  'Cart #',
  'Scheduled Title',
  'Actual Title',
  'Start Date',
  'End Date',
  'Scheduled Length',
  'Actual Length'

# Import the CSV - by reading it into memory _in full_ first -, select the
# properties and perform the transformation, then write back to the file.
(Import-Csv ./Values.csv) | # !! The (...) are required
  Select-Object $properties |
    Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation ./Values.csv
```

**Note the need to enclose the `Import-Csv` call in `(...)` in order to enforce reading its entire content *up front*, *in full* into memory, which is a prerequisite for being able to write back to the same file as part of the same pipeline.**
Without that, you would essentially *erase* the file.

Aside from concerns about available memory with large input files, also note that this method bears a **slight risk of data loss**, if the pipeline is interrupted before writing all (transformed) objects back to the input file has completed.

A more robust solution would be to write to a temporary file first, and replace the original file with the temporary file on successful completion.