# Use a for loop for list and set element to environment variable then get value

Tags: powershell, for-loop

I'm not familiar with powershell at all and only need it for a few commands. I was hoping that someone could assist me. I have a json file named `optionsConfig.json` that reads like so,

```
{
"test1": ["options_size", "options_connection", "options_object"],

"test2":["options_customArgs", "options_noUDP", "options_noName"]
}
```

In my powershell file, I have one line so far and this is to get the content of the json file.

`$rawData = Get-Content -Raw -Path "optionsConfig.json" | ConvertFrom-Json`

I had planned on having an environment variable on my system named `test` that would have the value of `test1` or `test2` and from that, I would look at the elements of the list in the associated value in the json file. With these elements from the list, I would assume that they are also environment variables and I would want to get their values. ( a list comprehension in python would be perfect here).I'm a python guy so I am not quite certain how to show this in powershell but say I did `env = getEnvironmentVariable(test)` and that equals `test1`. I would then say something like `for i in $rawData.env
        return getEnvironmentVariable(i)`

I pretty much want another list or new json object with the values for the assumed environment variables that we get from the original json object.

Is there a way that I can do this in powershell? It would help a lot if anyone could assist. I apologize if I wasn't clear with anything. Thanks

(edit) I see that `$rawData.Get-ChildItem Env:test` does not work. Is there someone to write something like this in order to get the correct list from json file?

Also setting a new variable like so `$var1 = Get-ChildItem Env.tool` and doing `$rawData.$test.value` has no effect either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Sample values: make environment variable 'test' ($env:test)
# point to property 'test1'
$env:test = 'test1'

# Provide sample values for the environment-variable names listed
# in the 'test1' property.
$env:options_size = 'size1'
$env:options_connection = 'conn1'
$env:options_object = 'obj1'


# Read the JSON file into a custom object.
$configObj = Get-Content -Raw optionsConfig.json | ConvertFrom-Json

# Retrieve the environment variables whose
# names are listed in the $env:test property ('test1' in this example),
# as name-value pairs.
Get-Item -Path env:* -Include $configObj.$env:test
```

The above yields an array of `[System.Collections.DictionaryEntry]` instances each representing an environment variable's name and value:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
options_connection             conn1
options_object                 obj1
options_size                   size1
```

---

To **convert the above to JSON**:

```
Get-Item -Path env:* -Include $configObj.$env:test |
  Select-Object Name, Value | ConvertTo-Json
```

Note: The seemingly redundant `Select-Object` call is necessary to strip additional properties that PowerShell adds behind the scenes, which would otherwise show in the resulting JSON.
If you wanted to *rename* the properties in the resulting JSON, you'd need `Select-Object` anyway, using [calculated properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39861920/45375).

This yields:

```
[
  {
    "Name": "options_connection",
    "Value": "conn1"
  },
  {
    "Name": "options_object",
    "Value": "obj1"
  },
  {
    "Name": "options_size",
    "Value": "size1"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a problem, just set and use `$ENV:test`

```
$rawdata = Get-Content .\optionsconfig.json | convertfrom-json
$Env:Test="test1"
$rawdata.$ENV:Test

$Env:Test="test2"
$rawdata.$ENV:Test
```

Sample output

```
options_size
options_connection
options_object

options_customArgs
options_noUDP
options_noName
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That definitely seems to work for finding those values. I wasn't aware of $ENV.