# Search for RegEx string in files and return ONLY file name, path and string

Tags: regex, string, powershell, search, return

i am kinda stuck with this search for Regex string. The scenario is as follows:

- I have a bunch of files of certain extension (*.tlt) with random content
- All the files are across the subfolders of BETA folder on drive F:
- Each one of the files has at least one **Revision 1.234** somewhere in the content. (sometimes multiple times - only the first appearance is important)

This is what I have so far:

```
$files = gci f:\beta\ -Include "*.tlt" -Recurse
$results = $files |
           Select-String -Pattern 'Revision:.+.{1}[.]\d{1,3}'|
           ForEach-Object { $_.Matches } |
           select Value |
           Format-Table -GroupBy Filename
```

What I need is a PowerShell script that searches through the files and returns the list of files with the full path and ONLY the Revision 1.234 but not the whole line.

Comment: Well, you are currently only selecting `value` so you can't group by `Filename`. Also, you shouldn't pipe to `Format-Table` if you are going to store the results. Store the results, and then display them with `Format-Table` later if desired. If you are only using it in order to group things, use `Group-Object` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I have now marked it and up-voted for both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single-pipeline solution is possible with the help of [calculated properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39861920/45375):

```
Get-ChildItem f:\beta -Filter *.tlt -Recurse | 
  Select-String -List -Pattern 'Revision:.+?\.\d{3}' |
    Select-Object @{ n='FullName'; e='Path' }, @{ n='Revision'; e={ $_.Matches.Value } }
```

Sample output:

```
FullName                              Revision
--------                              --------
/Users/jdoe/foo.tlt                   Revision: 1.234
/Users/jdoe/sub/bar.tlt               Revision: 10.235
```

- As mentioned in [TheIncorrigible1's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51958341/45375), using `-Filter` performs much better than using `-Include`, because `-Filter` filters *at the source* (lets the filesystem *provider* do the filtering) rather than collecting all file-info objects first and then letting *PowerShell* do the filtering.
- `Select-String -List` limits matching in each input file to the *first* match.
- Each match output by `Select-String` is a [`[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.commands.matchinfo) instance, which contains rich metadata about each match, such as `.Path` with the full input filename, and `.Matches` with information about what the regex (`-Pattern`) matched - this metadata is used to populate the output custom objects created by `Select-Object` via the aforementioned calculated properties.

Answer (score 2):

You were close, but you inevitably need to loop through your files.  Note `-Filter` is significantly faster than `-Include` since it doesn't collect every object before filtering.

```
$fileList = Get-ChildItem -Path F:\beta -Filter *.tlt -Recurse
$results = foreach ($file in $fileList)
{
    $find = $file | Select-String -Pattern '(Revision:.+?\.\d{1,3})'
    if ($find)
    {
        @{
            Path = $file.FullName
            Rev  = $find.Matches.Groups[0].Value
        }
    }
}
```