# PowerShell -ExpandProperty and correct date format

Tags: powershell, select-object

I am attempting to use the `-ExpandProperty` feature in PowerShell to stop the header appearing in the output and format the date without minutes and seconds. This is just to get the created date for an AD Object:

```
Get-ADComputer -Server $Server -Identity BlahBlah -Properties Created |
  Select-Object -ExpandProperty @{Name="Created";Expression={$_.Created.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")}}
```

This does not produce a result, only if I exclude the `"-ExpandProperty"` part will it produce the right date format BUT includes the header `"Created"` which I don't want.

Any ideas please?

Comment: Could you share the desired output you want? It is a bit unclear at the moment. To you just want the value from that field and nothing else? I mean - Do you want a list of objects or something else?

Comment: Mi Motz, I just want output from that field that looks like: 2018-07-03 not Created   
-------   
2018-07-03

Comment: An no other objects, details or nothing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have access to an AD at the moment, but this could be what you are after

**Updated**

```
Get-ADComputer -Server $Server -Identity BlahBlah -Properties Created | Select-Object Created | ForEach-Object {$_.Created.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")}
```

Answer (score 2):

In PowerShell there nearly always is more than one solution to a problem-

```
(Get-ADComputer -Server $Server -Identity BlahBlah -Properties Created | 
  Select-Object @{N="Created";E{$_.Created.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")}} ).Created
```

or

```
Get-ADComputer -Server $Server -Identity BlahBlah -Properties Created | 
  Select-Object @{N="Created";E{$_.Created.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")}} |
    Select-Object -Expand Created
```

Parameter names can be shorted as long as they are uniquely identifiable and there are also shortcuts (uppercase letters) so -EA is -ErrorAction

A calculated property does IMO make no sense here as it is the only output, so this should do also:

```
Get-ADComputer -Server $Server -Identity BlahBlah -Properties Created | 
  ForEach-Object {$_.Created.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")}
```

Comment: Thanks LotPings - that last one worked perfectly. I should have realized that using a for-each object made more sense than using a calculated property, as you say.

Answer (score 1):

To *complement* [LotPings' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53238612/45375), which offers effective solutions:

As for ***why* your code didn't work**:

While `Select-Object`'s `-Property` parameter accepts *hashtables* that define [calculated properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39861920/45375) (such as in your code), **the `-ExpandProperty` parameter only accepts a property *name*, as a *string***.

Therefore, your hashtable is simply *stringified*, resulting in string literal `System.Collections.Hashtable`, causing `Select-Object` to complain, given that there is no property by that name.

The **purpose of `-ExpandProperty` is to output just a property *value* rather than a custom object with that property**.
You therefore do not need a detour via `Select-Object`, and can just **use the value-outputting script block - `{ $_.Created.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") }` - directly with `ForEach-Object`** instead, as shown at the bottom of LotPings' answer.

---

However, there is an obscure feature that you forgo by using `ForEach-Object`: `Select-Object` allows *combining* `-ExpandProperty` with `-Property`, in which case the properties specified via `-Property` are added as `NoteProperty` members to the *value* of the property specified via `-ExpandProperty`:

```
PS> $val = [pscustomobject] @{ one = 'uno'; two = 2 } |
      Select-Object -ExpandProperty one -Property two; $val; $val.two
uno
2
```

Note how the output *string* value, `'uno'` has a copy of the input object's `.two` property attached to it.

To emulate that with `ForEach` requires more work:

```
PS> $val = [pscustomobject] @{ one = 'uno'; two = 2 } | ForEach-Object {
      $_.one + '!' | Add-Member -PassThru two $_.two
    }; $val; $val.two
uno!
2
```