# List file count by subfolder

Tags: powershell, subdirectory

I am trying to use powershell to produce a list of folder names and how many files are in each folder.

I have this script

```
$dir = "C:\Users\folder" 
Get-ChildItem $dir -Recurse -Directory | ForEach-Object{
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Folder = $_.FullName
        Count = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $_.Fullname -File).Count
    }
} | Select-Object Folder,Count
```

Which lists the file count, but it puts the full path (i.e. `C:\Users\name\Desktop\1\2\-movi...`). Is there any way to just display the last folder ("movies") as well as save the result to a .txt file?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `$_.FullName`, use `$_.Name` to only get the directory *name*.

Your `Select-Object` call is redundant - it is effectively a no-op.

While it's easy to send the results to a `.txt` file with `>`, for instance, it's better to use a more structured format for later *programmatic* processing.
In the simplest form, that means outputting to a CSV file via `Export-Csv`; generally, however, the most faithful way of serializing objects to a file is to use `Export-CliXml`.

Using `Export-Csv` for serialization:

```
$dir = 'C:\Users\folder'
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $dir -Recurse -Directory | ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject] @{
      Folder = $_.Name
      Count = @(Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $_.Fullname -File).Count
    }
} | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation results.csv
```

Note that you could streamline your command by replacing the `ForEach-Object` call with a `Select-Object` call that uses a [*calculated property*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39861920/45375):

```
$dir = 'C:\Users\folder'
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $dir -Recurse -Directory |
  Select-Object Name,
    @{ n='Count'; e={@(Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $_.Fullname -File).Count} } |
      Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation results.csv
```

Comment: My pleasure, @MikeP. Please see my update for how you could streamline your command. Generally, use the `Get-Member` cmdlet to inspect a command's output types, so you can discover the full type name and available properties / methods.

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this...

```
Clear-Host
Get-ChildItem -Path 'd:\temp' -Recurse -Directory | 
Select-Object Name,FullName,
@{Name='FileCount';Expression = {(Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -File -Recurse| Measure-Object).Count}} `
| Format-Table -AutoSize

# Results


Name           FullName                               FileCount
----           --------                               ---------
abcpath0       D:\temp\abcpath0                               5
abcpath1       D:\temp\abcpath1                               5
abcpath2       D:\temp\abcpath2                               5
Duplicates     D:\temp\Duplicates                         12677
EmptyFolder    D:\temp\EmptyFolder                            0
NewFiles       D:\temp\NewFiles                               4
PngFiles       D:\temp\PngFiles                               4
results        D:\temp\results                              905
...
```