# Getting "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]" in CSV File export when data is okay on screen

Tags: arrays, powershell, csv, stringify, export-csv

I am new to PowerShell and trying to get a list of VM names and their associated IP Addresses from within Hyper-V.

I am getting the information fine on the screen but when I try to export to csv all I get for the IP Addresses is `` System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] `` on each line.

There are suggestions about "joins" or "ConvertTo-CSV" but I don't understand the syntax for these.

Can anyone help?

This is the syntax I am using...

```
Get-VM | Select -ExpandProperty VirtualNetworkAdapters | select name, IPV4Addresses | Export-Csv -Path "c:\Temp\VMIPs.csv"
```

Comment: if you save the output of the 2nd `Select-Object` to a $Var and do `$Var.GetType()` on it, what you you see? what about `$Var.IPV4Addresses.Get-Type()`?

Comment: Did you know `Export-Csv` has a very useful switch called [NoTypeInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-6) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an object you export as CSV with `Export-Csv` or `ConvertTo-Csv` has **property values that contain a *collection* (array)** of values, these values are **stringified via their `.ToString()` method**, which results in an unhelpful representation, as in the case of your array-valued `.IPV4Addresses` property.

To demonstrate this with the `ConvertTo-Csv` cmdlet (which works analogously to `Export-Csv`, but *returns* the CSV data instead of saving it to a file):

```
PS> [pscustomobject] @{ col1 = 1; col2 = 2, 3 } | ConvertTo-Csv
"col1","col2"
"1","System.Object[]"
```

That is, the array `2, 3` stored in the `.col2` property was unhelpfully stringified as `System.Object[]`, which is what you get when you call `.ToString()` on a regular PowerShell array; other .NET collection types - such as `[System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]` in your case - stringify analogously; that is, by their *type name*.

---

Assuming you want to represent all values of an array-valued property in a *single* CSV column, to fix this problem **you must *decide on a meaningful string representation* for the collection as a whole** and implement it using **`Select-Object` with a [calculated property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39861920/45375)**:

E.g., you can use the `-join` operator to create a space-separated list of the elements:

```
PS> [pscustomobject] @{ col1 = 1; col2 = 2, 3 } | 
      Select-Object col1, @{ n='col2'; e={ $_.col2 -join ' ' } } |
        ConvertTo-Csv
"col1","col2"
"1","2 3"
```

Note how array `2, 3` was turned into string `'2 3'`.

Answer (score 0):

OtherObjectPipedStuff | Select-object name,IPV4Addresses | export-csv PP.csv -NoTypeinformation

Comment: There's no meaningful difference between the OP's own attempt and your command (except the addition of `-NoTypeInformation`, which is _incidental_ to the problem at hand). Also, please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).