# Export NSG rules to a csv file using powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-nsg

I am trying to use powershell to export all Network Security Group (NSG) rules across all subscriptions in Azure.

```
  $sub = Get-AzSubscription
  $sub | foreach-object {
  $null = $PSItem | Select-AzSubscription
  $null = Get-AzNetworkSecurityGroup -OutVariable +nsg
  foreach ($obj in $nsg)
  {
   $obj.SecurityRules | Select-Object -OutVariable +rules @{ n = 'NSG Name'; e = {$obj.Name}},
   @{ n = 'ResourceGroupName'; e = {$obj.ResourceGroupName}},
   *
  }
   }


 $rules | export-csv C:\Users\ABC\Desktop\NSG.csv
```

However, the exported csv files has many field with "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]", even though I can see the for loop is running fine and all the data is generated.

I am very new to powershell so any help on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If an object you export as CSV with `Export-Csv` or `ConvertTo-Csv` has property values that contain a collection (array) of values, these values are stringified via their `.ToString()` method, which results in an unhelpful representation.

Assuming you want to represent all values of an array-valued property in a single CSV column, to fix this problem **you must decide on a meaningful string representation for the collection as a whole** and implement it using `Select-Object` with a [calculated property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39840883/create-objects-with-custom-properties-containing-derived-filesystem-path-informa/39861920#39861920):

E.g., you can use the -join operator to create a space-separated list of the elements:

```
$obj.SecurityRules | Select-Object -OutVariable +rules @{ n = 'NSG Name'; e = {$obj.Name -join ' '}}, @{ n = 'ResourceGroupName'; e = {$obj.ResourceGroupName -join ' '}},*
```

For more details, you could refer to this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55105971/getting-system-collections-generic-list1system-string-in-csv-file-export-wh).

Comment: Thanks, i am not sure how I can export the csv, after running the above command?

Comment: Just add `e = {$obj.Name -join ' '}` to `select-object`. It will  not affect you to export csv.