# PowerShell : How can I set a variable from a single column in multi-column output?

Tags: powershell, variables, output

I am using `Get-PhysicalDisk | Format-Table DeviceID, UniqueID` to get a listing of drive number and serial number of all drives on a Windows 2016 Server.  I want to search for one serial number and capture only the drive number as a variable.  I'm used to awk in UNIX and I'm totally stumped on how to achieve this in PowerShell.

```
Get-PhysicalDisk | Format-Table DeviceID, UniqueID

DeviceID UniqueID                              
-------- --------                              
5        624A937024897B4FF488CBF800027A4B      
8        624A937024897B4FF488CBF800028A4D      
7        624A937024897B4FF488CBF800027A59      
0        {c4d394f5-509e-11e9-a834-806e6f6e6963}
1        {c4d394f6-509e-11e9-a834-806e6f6e6963}
2        {c4d394f7-509e-11e9-a834-806e6f6e6963}
3        {c4d394f8-509e-11e9-a834-806e6f6e6963}
4        {c4d394f9-509e-11e9-a834-806e6f6e6963}
6        624A937024897B4FF488CBF800027A56
```

I want to expand this command to find SerialNumber `624A937024897B4FF488CBF800027A56` then set a variable called `$DriveNumber` to the value of `6` as shown in the output.

I then plan to use this variable in `Set-Disk` to take the drive offline/online as a perform a volume overwrite.  I don't want to hard code the drive number because upon reboot, the drive number could change.
*NOTE* I was using `Get-Disk` and piping the appropriate output to `Set-Disk` to perform my drive off/online.  But, I have a mysterious issue of the virtual drives not displaying with `Get-Disk`, therefore I'm trying to find a workaround with `Get-PhysicalDisk` Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$driveNumber = (
  Get-PhysicalDisk | Where-Object UniqueId -eq '{624A937024897B4FF488CBF800027A56}'
).DeviceId
```

<sup>Note the need to enclose the GUID string in `{...}`.</sup>

As all PowerShell cmdlets do, `Get-PhysicalDisk` outputs *objects* whose properties you can query.

Cmdlet `Where-Object` acts as a filter on the objects it receives from the pipeline and compares the value of property `UniqueId` to the specified literal GUID (string), which, by definition, matches (at most) *one* object.

`(...).DeviceId` returns the value of the target objects' `DeviceId` property  and assigns it to variable `$driveNumber`.

---

#### A note re use of `Format-*` cmdlets such as `Format-Table`:

Only ever use `Format-*` cmdlets for *display formatting*.

If the intent is further *programmatic processing*:

- either: **simply access the input objects' intrinsic properties** (whose availability is independent of whether they *display* by default or via a `Format-*` cmdlet call)
- or: **if you need to create *simplified or transformed objects*** with only a subset of the original properties and/or transformed property property values ([calculated properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39861920/45375), use [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object).

Comment: @RightCoaster: You're missing the `{...}` around the GUID. What is _displayed_ is irrelevant in PowerShell - what matters is what properties the objects intrinsically have. Note that `Format-*` cmdlets should only ever be used for _display formatting_ - never if the intent is further _programmatic processing_.

Comment: @RightCoaster - just in case mklement0 hasn't made it _painfully_ clear ... the `Format-*` cmdlets take your objects, **_butcher them_**, and send out the remnants wrapped in _formatting code_. to see what i am talking about try this ... >> $Test = $PSVersionTable | Format-Table; $Test.Count; $Test[1]` << note the red error text about `Out-LineOutput` ... [*grin*]