# How to return the fullname with measure-object attributes

Tags: powershell

I'm a bit new to PowerShell.  I have a working script returning `-Line`, `-Character` and `-Word` to a csv file. I can't figure out how to add the full name of the file into the csv.

```
get-childitem -recurse -Path C:\Temp\*.* | foreach-object { $name = $_.FullName; get-content $name | Measure-Object -Line -Character -Word} | Export-Csv -Path C:\Temp\FileAttributes.csv
```

I've tried using `Write-Host` and `Select-Object`, but I'm not sure about the syntax.

I've been using the following as a [reference](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-a-powershell-cmdlet-to-count-files-words-and-lines/).

#### Results

[image: screenshot]

#### This is what I'm after

[image: solution]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Select-Object` with a [calculated property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39861920/45375):

```
Get-Childitem -recurse -Path C:\Temp\*.* | ForEach-Object { 
  $fullName = $_.FullName
  Get-Content $fullName | Measure-Object -Line -Character -Word |
    Select-Object @{ Name = 'FullName'; Expression={ $fullName } }, *
} | Export-Csv -Path C:\Temp\FileAttributes.csv
```

Note:

- Pass `-ExcludeProperty Property` to `Select-Object` to omit the empty `Property` column.
- Pass `-NoTypeInformation` to `Export-Csv` to suppress the virtually useless first line (the type annotation) in the CSV.

Comment: I now have a much more complete script in [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/222458/158032)