# Why is this Hashtable producing incorrect result?

Tags: powershell

I have the following:

```
$roles = 'role1;role2;role3;role4' -split ';'
$members = 'member1,member2;;member3;member4' -split ';'
```

this basically means, for every semicolon, its a new "index".

parsed, this should generate the following output:

```
Role  Members
----  -------
role1 member1,member2
role2
role3 member3
role4 member4
```

i want to access objects by name, i am using hashtable, but for some reason, its not working properly.

```
$roleMembers = @{}

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $roles.Count; $i++) {
  # `Where Length -ne 0` to filter out empty strings
  $roleMembers[$roles[$i]] = $members[($i*2)..($i*2+1)] | Where Length -ne 0
}
```

`PS> $roleMembers` outputs

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
role1                          member1,member2
role3
role4
role2                          {member3, member4}
```

how come the output is incorrect? only role 1 is correct, while role3 and role4 are incorrectly empty, and role2 should be empty but isntead it has members3 and member4.

the expected result should be:

```
Role  Members
----  -------
role1 member1,member2
role2
role3 member3
role4 member4
```

also, i want the column names to be Role , Members instead of Name, Value respectively

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do it :

```
$roleMembers = [ordered]@{}

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $roles.Count; $i++) {
  $roleMembers[$roles[$i]] = $members[$i]
}
```

Comment: I have modified my code for keep the results ordered

Comment: picking this as answer since it addresses the hashtable per the post, and also, this allows me to easily access members by name. but @vrdse's answer is also a nice alternative!

Comment: I agree, i use often pscustomobject too

Answer (score 3):

Use the counter `$i` to get the right element (no need to make any calculations here), remove the where-filter and make it a `PSCustomObject` to get the role and members properties.

```
    $roles = 'role1;role2;role3;role4' -split ';'
    $members = 'member1,member2;;member3;member4' -split ';'


    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $roles.Count; $i++) {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                    Roles   = $roles[$i]
                    Members = $members[$i]
            }
    }
```

This produces the expected output

```
    Roles Members        
    ----- -------
    role1 member1,member2
    role2
    role3 member3
    role4 member4
```

Comment: nice! i am setting $var to get the result of the for pscutomobject stored in a variable to access properties. I can do something like: $var.roles[1], and i get role2. i can do $var.members and i get the list of members. but how can i access members for a certain role? for example, $var.Roles[0].Members doesnt output anything (member1, member2), nor does accessing it by name work: $var.Roles['role1'].Members

Comment: By index `$var[0]` or a where-filter `$var | Where-Object {$_.Roles -eq 'role1'}`

Comment: @mklement0 The OP also asked that it have column headers of 'Role' and 'Members', which implies custom objects. I think a combination of the two is likely in order. a hashtable with the roles as keys, and custom objects as the values.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician: I cleaned up my original comments, so just to provide context (again): This answer covers the column-headers aspect of the question, but not the access-by-role-name aspect, whereas the opposite is true of Esperento57's answer. Your proposed solution is a way of  covering both aspects, though for having specific column names merely _for display_ a more lightweight alternative is to stick with a simple (ordered) hashtable and just use `Format-Table` to provide for-display output with custom column names. My answer now shows both solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Your question has two unrelated requirements:

- To create an (ordered) **data structure that maps roles to members** that **supports direct lookup by name**.

  - [Esperento57's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57315269/45375) covers that aspect, by creating an *ordered hashtable*.
- To **provide tabular output of the resulting data structure** with **specific column names**.

  - [vrdse's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57315217/45375) covers that aspect, by creating an *array of custom objects* with properties named `Roles` and `Members`, which PowerShell automatically uses as column headers when it prints custom objects to the screen.

There are two ways to address *both* requirements:

---

Solution A: **If the custom column names are needed for *display* only:**

Pipe the `$roleMembers` hashtable from Esperento57's answer to `Format-Table` and provide the desired column names via [calculated properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39861920/45375), which in this case effectively rename the hashtable entries' `Key` property to `Roles`, and `Value` to `Members`:

```
PS> $roleMembers | Format-Table @{ n='Role'; e='Key' }, @{ n='Members'; e='Value' }

Role  Members
----  -------
role1 member1,member2
role2
role3 member3
role4 member4
```

Note that `Format-Table` output, as with all `Format-*` cmdlets, is suitable for *display* only, not for later programmatic processing.

---

Solution B: **If you want to keep objects around with properties named `Role` and `Members`** for later processing:

As suggested by [TheMadTechnician](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3245749/themadtechnician), *combine* the two solutions by making the hashtable values contain *custom objects* rather than just the list of members:

```
$roles = 'role1;role2;role3;role4' -split ';'
$members = 'member1,member2;;member3;member4' -split ';'

$rolesAndMembers = [ordered] @{}
foreach ($i in 0..($roles.Count-1)) {
  $rolesAndMembers[$roles[$i]] = [pscustomobject] @{
    Role = $roles[$i]
    Members = $members[$i]
  }
}

# Outputting .Values enumerates the custom objects stored in the hashtable.
# Because the custom objects have fewer than 5 properties, Format-Table is
# implied for output formatting, and the custom objects' property names
# are used as column headers.
$rolesAndMembers.Values
```

This yields the same output as above.

Note that the implication is that in order to access, say, `role1`'s members, you'll have to use:

```
$rolesAndMembers.role1.Members # -> 'member1,member2'
# or: $rolesAndMembers['role1'].Members
```

As an aside: if you wanted to store members *individually* rather than as  a string list, `-split` them on custom-object creation:

```
[pscustomobject] @{
    Role = $roles[$i]
    Members = $members[$i] -split ','  # Members becomes an array with member names
}
```

`$rolesAndMembers.role1.Members[0]` would then yield `member1`, for instance, and `$rolesAndMembers.role1.Members[1]` would yield `member2`.

---

As for **what you tried**:

`$members[($i*2)..($i*2+1)]` accesses *2* array elements at an index that is *twice* that of `$i`.

However, your `$roles` and `$members` arrays have a one-to-one correspondence: they have the same number of elements and for all indices the values directly relate to each other; therefore `$members[$i]` must be used.