# Unable to select the column names of a Variable in powershell

Tags: powershell

I unable to see data of a column of a variable in Powershell.

I have dumped the result of a command Get-AzVMUsage -Location WestUS2 to a variable `$Data`.

Now, when I select the 4 columns that result from the variable `$Data`, I'm not able to see accurate of one of the column "**Name**".

```
$Data = Get-AzVMUsage -Location $Location
$Data | select Name,CurrentValue,Limit,Unit
```

Below is the attached output that I'm getting. in which the column "**Name**" is having same weird values.
   [image: Output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.Name` property of the objects output by `Get-AzVMUsage` cmdlet is of type [`UsageName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.compute.models.usagename?view=azure-dotnet).

When this property is stringified for display, it uses only the *type name*, which is unhelpful.

To get meaningful output, you either have to access the `.Value` or `.LocalizedValue` property, and in order to do so you must use a [*calculated property*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39861920/45375); e.g.:

```
$Data | select @{ n='Name'; e={ $_.Name.Value } }, CurrentValue, Limit, Unit
```