# Powershell Get-Service command outputs service code instead of text status?

Tags: powershell

I have pretty simple code that iterates over the output of `Get-Service | Select Name, DisplayName, Status` and then formats it into a json object. The problem I am facing is running that command outside of my powershell script returns the actual textual status (RUNNING, STOPPED, etc), but in the script the status is numeric (1-4). I am currently running PS Version `5.1.18362.145`

Script:

```
$services = Get-Service | Select Name, DisplayName, Status

$services.ForEach({
    Add-Member -NotePropertyName 'table' -NotePropertyValue 'Status' -InputObject $_;
})

$payload = @{
    metrics = @($services)
} | ConvertTo-Json

Write-Output ($payload)
```

Example Output:

```
                    {
                        "Name":  "WPDBusEnum",
                        "DisplayName":  "Portable Device Enumerator Service",
                        "Status":  1,
                        "table":  "Status"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name":  "WpnService",
                        "DisplayName":  "Windows Push Notifications System Service",
                        "Status":  4,
                        "table":  "Status"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name":  "WpnUserService_8be1a",
                        "DisplayName":  "Windows Push Notifications User Service_8be1a",
                        "Status":  4,
                        "table":  "Status"
                    }
```

I would prefer for `Status` to remain textual instead of numeric. Is this something specific to PS 5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
$services = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
foreach ($service in (Get-Service)){
    $services.Add(@{"Name"= $service.Name; "DisplayName" = $service.DisplayName; "Status" = $service.Status.ToString()}) | Out-Null
}

$payload = @{
    metrics = @($services)
} | ConvertTo-Json

Write-Output ($payload)
```

Answer (score 3):

The **`.Status` property** of the [`[System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller) instances that cmdlet [`Get-Service`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-service) outputs is of type [`[System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicecontrollerstatus), which is an ***enumeration* type** (derived from [`[System.Enum]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum)): that is, it associates symbolic names with numeric values; e.g., symbolic name `Stopped` is associated with the number `1`.

**[`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json) serializes such enumeration values as *numbers***:

- *invariably* in Windows PowerShell.
- *by default* in PowerShell *Core*; you can opt to use the symbolic names (as *strings*) instead by using the `-EnumsAsStrings` switch.

In Windows PowerShell you therefore have to explicitly **convert the symbolic names to strings *before* calling `ConvertTo-Json`**, which you can achieve with a [calculated property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39861920/45375); here's a simplified example:

```bsh
Get-Service | 
  Select-Object Name, 
                DisplayName, 
                @{ n='Status'; e={ $_.Status.ToString() } },
                @{ n='table'; e={ 'Status' } } | 
    ConvertTo-Json
```

The above yields something like the following; note that the `"Status"` property now contains strings representing the symbolic names of the enumeration type:

```
{
    "Name":  "AppIDSvc",
    "DisplayName":  "Application Identity",
    "Status":  "Stopped",
    "table":  "Status"
},
{
    "Name":  "Appinfo",
    "DisplayName":  "Application Information",
    "Status":  "Running",
    "table":  "Status"
}
...
```

---

Applied to your scenario:

```bsh
[pscustomobject] @{
  metrics = @(
    Get-Service | 
      select Name, 
             DisplayName, 
             @{ n='Status'; e={ $_.Status.ToString() } },
             @{ n='table'; e={ 'Status' } }
  )
} | ConvertTo-Json
```

Note how use of a single pipeline is sufficient.