# powershell - How refer custom expression property on single one select-object

Tags: powershell

can you help me with this simple example script?
How do I refer to "custom expression property" on single one "select-object"?

I would like: **single "select-object"**

```
Get-Process | Select-Object Id, 
    @{name="MyProp"; expression={$_.id}},
    @{name="MyPropRef"; expression={$_.MyProp}}
```

...but third property "MyPropRef" is not displayed!

```
   Id MyProp MyPropRef
   -- ------ ---------
 3780   3780
```

While with *double select-object piped*, "MyPropRef" is displayed

```
Get-Process | Select-Object Id, 
    @{name="MyProp"; expression={$_.id}} | Select-Object *,
    @{name="MyPropRef"; expression={$_.MyProp}}

   Id MyProp MyPropRef
   -- ------ ---------
 3780   3780      3780
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Calculated properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39861920/45375) only operate on the input objects' *original properties*, they cannot refer *to each other*.

If you need to add additional properties based on previously calculated properties, you indeed need another (expensive) `Select-Object` call.

Your command:

```
Get-Process | Select-Object Id, 
    @{name="MyProp"; expression={$_.id}},
    @{name="MyPropRef"; expression={$_.MyProp}}
```

*creates* a `.MyPropRef` property, but its value is `$null`, because the `System.Diagnostics.Process` instances that `Get-Process` outputs themselves do not have a `.MyPropRef` property.

---

If you want to make do with a single `Select-Object` call without repetition, you can define the script blocks used in the calculated properties in *variables* beforehand and reuse them across calculated property definitions; e.g.:

```
$myPropExpr = { $_.id }
Get-Process | Select-Object Id, 
    @{ name="MyProp"; expression=$myPropExpr },
    @{ name="MyPropRef"; expression={ "!" + (& $myPropExpr) }}
```

This would yield something like:

```
Id   MyProp  MyPropRef
--   ------  ---------
3780   3780      !3780
...
```