# Comparing two CSV's for similar strings

Tags: powershell, active-directory, data-cleaning

I am currently trying to compare two CSV's. doc1 has 5000 strings in it, and doc2 has 100 strings in it. Every string in doc2 ends in "admin". I want to compare doc1 & doc2 and find all the strings that match up to the point it reaches "admin".

so as an example:

a string in doc1

a string in doc1 admin

it will output both of these to a new CSV

```
results = foreach ($OU in $OUs) { 
Get-ADGroup -SearchBase $OU -Filter * -Properties CanonicalName,Created,Description,ManagedBy,Member,MemberOf,Members,ObjectGUID,whenChanged | 
? {($_.ManagedBy -like $null) -and ($_.Description -notlike "*owner*") -and ($_.CanonicalName -notlike "*admin")}
}
$results | select CanonicalName,Description,ManagedBy,Member,MemberOf,Members,ObjectGUID,Created,whenChanged |
Export-Csv .\doc1.csv -NoTypeInformation

$results0 = foreach ($OU in $OUs) { 
Get-ADGroup -SearchBase $OU -Filter * -Properties CanonicalName,Created,Description,ManagedBy,Member,MemberOf,Members,ObjectGUID,whenChanged | 
? {($_.ManagedBy -like $null) -and ($_.Description -notlike "*owner*") -and ($_.CanonicalName -like "*admin")}
}
$results0 | select CanonicalName,Description,ManagedBy,Member,MemberOf,Members,ObjectGUID,Created,whenChanged |
Export-Csv .\doc2.csv -NoTypeInformation

$csvPath1 = ".\doc1.csv"
$csvPath2 = '.\doc2.csv'
$propertyToCompare = 'CanonicalName'
$csv1 = Import-Csv -Path $csvPath1
$csv2 = Import-Csv -Path $csvPath2
$duplicates = Compare-Object $csv1 $csv2 -Property $propertyToCompare -ExcludeDifferent -PassThru | Select-Object -ExpandProperty $propertyToCompare
$csv1 | Where-Object { $_.$propertyToCompare -in $duplicates } | Export-Csv -Path .\AdminsAndNotAdminsInOneFile.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

With Compare-Object I don't know how to make it ignore the last few characters in the string in doc2. Is there some way for me to modify the string?

Comment: I don't know what field has the requirement, but you can do `($string -replace 'admin$').Trim()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact that `Compare-Object` supports [calculated properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39861920/45375) as comparison properties (here, only a script block (`{...}`) is passed, which is the same as passing
`@{ Expression = { ... } }`):

```
Compare-Object $csv1 $csv2 -ExcludeDifferent -IncludeEqual -PassThru -Property {
    $_.$propertyToCompare -replace ' admin$'
  } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty $propertyToCompare
```

Note that `-PassThru` ensures that the input objects are passed through, which in the case of objects that compare as *equal* means that the *LHS* (`$csv1`) object is passed through.

Expression `$_.$propertyToCompare -replace ' admin$'`, which is evaluated for each input object, uses regex `admin$` to  [replace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) `' admin'` at the end (`$`) of the value of property `$propertyToCompare`; if that string isn't present, the value is used as-is.

In effect, the objects are compared as if the trailing `' admin'` weren't present.