# How to compare two tables with one column that is slightly different in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, compareobject

I would like to compare the version info of files from two different directories.

I could do this:

```
$files1 = (Get-Item "$path1\*.dll").VersionInfo
$files2 = (Get-Item "$path2\*.dll").VersionInfo
compare-object $files1 $files2
```

But then I get something like:

```
InputObject
-----------
File:             path1\AxInterop.ShDocVw.dll...
File:             path1\dom.dll...
(etc...)
File:             path2\AxInterop.ShDocVw.dll...
File:             path2\dom.dll...
(etc...)
```

I guess I could do something like:

```
$files1 = (Get-Item "$path1\*.dll").VersionInfo.ProductVersion
$files2 = (Get-Item "$path2\*.dll").VersionInfo.ProductVersion
compare-object $files1 $files2
$files1 = (Get-Item "$path1\*.dll").VersionInfo.FileVersion
$files2 = (Get-Item "$path2\*.dll").VersionInfo.FileVersion
compare-object $files1 $files2
```

but then if there is a difference, I'd have to go looking for what that difference is.  I can't compare the files directly because one set is signed and the other isn't.

What would the best way to do this?

To clarify, the current `compare-object` cmdlet doesn't meet my needs because it shows the filename as different because it shows that they have different paths. This is irrelevant to me.

I would like to compare rows with the same filename but different version numbers. If a difference in version number is observed for the same filename or a filename doesn't exist in one of the tables, then show the difference.

Comment: You should tell `Compare-Object` what property it should use to compare ... `Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $files1 -DifferenceObject $files2 -Property FileName,FileVersion`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`Compare-Object`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/) cmdlet's `-Property` parameter to compare and output the properties of interest.

[`Group-Object`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/) allows grouping the resulting objects, and [`Select-Object`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/) can be used to produce a single output object per file name from the group objects:

```
$files1 = (Get-Item $path1\*.dll).VersionInfo
$files2 = (Get-Item $path2\*.dll).VersionInfo

Compare-Object $files1 $files2 -Property { Split-Path -Leaf $_.FileName }, 
                                         ProductVersion, 
                                         FileVersion |
  Group-Object -Property ' Split-Path -Leaf $_.FileName ' | 
    Select-Object Name, 
           @{ n = 'SideIndicator'; e = { $_.Group.SideIndicator } },
           @{ n = 'ProductVersion'; e = { $_.Group.ProductVersion -join ' <-> ' } }, 
           @{ n = 'FileVersion'; e = { $_.Group.FileVersion -join ' <-> ' } }
```

Note the use of [*calculated properties*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39861920/45375) to compare the input objects by file *name* only, and to later extract information from `Group-Object`'s output via `Select-Object`.

Unfortunately, `Compare-Object`, as of PowerShell [Core] 7.0, doesn't allow you to *name* calculated properties<sup>[1]</sup>, and the *implied* property name is the literal contents of the script block (`{ ... }`),
 `Split-Path -Leaf $_.FileName` , which is what must be passed to `Group-Object -Property`.

The above yields something like the following:

```
Name         SideIndicator ProductVersion              FileVersion
----         ------------- --------------              -----------
file1234.exe {=>, <=}      7.0.18362.1 <-> 7.0.18365.0 7.0.18362.1 <-> 7.0.18365.0
file1235.exe <=            10.0.18362.1                10.0.18362.1
```

That is, for files present in *both* locations but with differing version numbers, `SideIndicator` shows
`{=>, <=}`, with the potentially differing version numbers in the `*Version` properties separated by `<->`

---

<sup>[1] Adding the ability to name calculated properties in the context of `Compare-Object` is the subject of [this GitHub feature request](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11607).</sup>

Comment: Glad to hear it was helpful, @Adrian; my pleasure.