# How do I rename properties on export to a CSV file?

Tags: powershell, csv, rename

I create a script that shows me a list of users starting with letter A.
Now I want to export them to a CSV file with columns named `full name`, `username`, `creation date`.

The following exports the desired column *values*, but doesn't have the column *names* (headers) that I want.

```
Get-ADUser -Properties whenCreated -Filter {samaccountname -like 'A*'} | 
  Select-Object name, SamAccountName, whenCreated | 
    export-csv -path c:\userexport.csv
```

Comment: Can you show what you want the CSV file to look like?  Including the header record and at least one dummy data record.

Comment: As an aside: While seductively convenient, it's best to [avoid the use of script blocks (`{ ... }`) as `-Filter` arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44184818/45375).

Comment: As Vad's answer shows, properties can be renamed via [calculated properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39861920/45375).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rename output properties like this:

```
Get-ADUser -Properties whenCreated -Filter {samaccountname -like 'A*'} | 
  Select-Object @{n='FullName';e={$_.Name}},@{n='Login';e={$_.SamaccountName}},@{n='When was Created';e={$_.WhenCreated}} |
    Export-Csv -path c:\userexport.csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ';' -Encoding UTF8
```

To later read in the resulting CSV filter and filter chronologically by the `When was Created` column, as requested in a follow-up question in the comments:

```
Import-Csv -Path D:\testdir\userexport.csv -Delimiter ';' |
  Where-Object {[datetime]::parseexact($_.'When was Created','dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss',$null) -le (Get-Date).AddYears(-2)} |
    Select-Object FullName
```

Comment: Question, Now do I need to import the file and output anyone who works over two years just his full name how do I do it? i think that i need start the script Import-Csv -Path C:\userexport.csv

Comment: Please don't use the curly brackets in the Filter. That parameter should be a **string**, not a script block. Write `-Filter "samaccountname -like 'A*'"` instead. Also add the `-NoTypeInformation` switch to the Export-Csv cmdlet.

Comment: Nice; aside from @Theo's comment it's also worth noting that you don't need a script block if _renaming_ is the only thing the calculated property does - the _name_ of the input property as a _string_ will do; e.g., `@{n='FullName';e={$_.Name}}` can be simplified to `@{n='FullName';e='Name'}`

Comment: @nadavshlomo Please do not ask a new question as comment to an answer of your original question.