# Use of Select-Object to change a property's data type and to add calculated properties

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-data-lake, select-object

Trying to get details from object and want to save it to SQL table.

```
$GetFiles `
    | Select-Object -Property  Name, Type `
    | Write-SqlTableData -ServerInstance $SQLServer -DatabaseName $SQLDatabase -SchemaName $SQLSchema -TableName $SQLTable -Credential $SQLCredential -Force
```

Que.1. Above code fails with error. Removing Type column works. But any way to cast Type property to string?

Write-SqlTableData : A mapping between .Net type 'Microsoft.Azure.Commands.DataLakeStore.Models.DataLakeStoreEnums+FileType' and SQL type for column 'Type' was not found. 
Consider removing the column with that type and repeat the operation.

Que.2. I also want to add an extra column say RowInsertedDate which will have current timestamp and one more hardcoded column say LoadStatus having value "Started". How to add it select clause?

Que.3. Anyway to truncate this table and then write data to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use *calculated properties* with `Select-Object`, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39861920/45375):

Re **1**, converting the `Type` property values to strings (`[string]`):

```
$GetFiles |
  Select-Object -Property Name, @{ Name='Type'; Expression = { [string] $_.Type } }
```

---

Re **2**, adding a `RowInsertedDate` column with a timestamp, and a `LoadStatus` column with fixed value `'Started'`:

```
$timestamp = Get-Date
$GetFiles |
  Select-Object Name, 
                @{ Name='Type'; Expression = { $_.Type.ToString() } },
                @{ Name='RowInsertedDate'; Expression = { $timestamp } },
                @{ Name='LoadStatus'; Expression = { 'Started' } }
```

<sup>Note: Positional arguments implicitly bind to the `-Property` parameter.</sup>

---

Re **3**, truncating the target table first:

I can't personally verify this, but I presume you need to use the [`Invoke-SqlCmd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd) cmdlet with the
[U-SQL `TRUNCATE TABLE` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/u-sql/ddl/tables/truncate-table) (since you're using Azure Data Lake).

Something along the following lines - obviously, **use caution**, because truncation is irreversible:

```
# UNTESTED. Note that TRUNCATE is IRREVERSIBLE.
Invoke-SqlCmd -Query "TRUNCATE TABLE $SQLSchema.$SQLTable" `
  -ServerInstance $SQLServer -Database $SQLDatabase -Credential $SQLCredential -Force
```