# How to group arrays in Powershell?

Tags: arrays, powershell, grouping

What is the easy and efficient way to transform an array using PowerShell?
An initial array has two properties `Number` and `Color`.

```
Number  Color
1       Red
2       Red
3       Red
4       Red
5       Blue
6       Blue
7       Green
8       Green
9       Green
```

An output array should like:

```
Color   Number
Red     1,2,3,4
Blue    5,6
Green   7,8,9
```

Comment: Have you looked at `Group-Object`?  That's a pretty common cmdlet for exactly this purpose.  Also, why would `5` and `6` be grouped under both `Red` and `Blue` in the output?

Comment: I couldn't get the needed output using Group-Object. it's an error - 5,6 should be in blue only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
# Input objects.
$objects = @'
Number,Color
1,Red
2,Red
3,Red
4,Red
5,Blue
6,Blue
7,Green
8,Green
9,Green
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$objects |
  Group-Object Color |
  Select-Object @{ n='Color'; e='Name'}, @{ n='Number'; e={ $_.Group.Number } }
```

The above yields:

```
Color Number
----- ------
Blue  {5, 6}
Green {7, 8, 9}
Red   {1, 2, 3, 4}
```

Note: Due to how `Group-Object` works, the `Color` values are sorted alphabetically in the output.

See also:

- [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Group-Object)
- [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Select-Object) with [calculated properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39861920/45375).

Answer (score 1):

Adding to [@mklement0's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61490684/how-to-group-arrays-in-powershell/61491369#61491369) great answer using `Group-Object`, we can also group the items into a [`System.Collections.Hashtable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable?view=netcore-3.1) by adding the `-AsHashTable` switch. To iterate the hashtable keys and values, we have to use [`System.Collections.Hashtable.GetEnumerator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable.getenumerator?view=netcore-3.1).

```
$objects = @'
Number,Color
1,Red
2,Red
3,Red
4,Red
5,Blue
6,Blue
7,Green
8,Green
9,Green
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$ht = $objects | Group-Object -Property Color -AsHashTable

$ht.GetEnumerator() | 
    Select-Object @{Name="Color";Expression={$_.Key}}, @{Name="Number";Expression={$_.Value | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Number}}
```

Output:

```
Color Number
----- ------
Green {7, 8, 9}
Red   {1, 2, 3, 4}
Blue  {5, 6}
```

If we want to sort your result by `Number`, we can use [`Sort-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object?view=powershell-7) to sort by the first number:

```
$ht.GetEnumerator() | 
    Select-Object @{Name="Color";Expression={$_.Key}}, @{Name="Number";Expression={$_.Value | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Number}} |
        Sort-Object @{Expression={$_.Number[0]}}
```

Or use an [`System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary?view=netcore-3.1) to create an ordered hashtable of arrays and maintain order of key insertion:

```
$ht = [ordered]@{}
foreach ($object in $objects) {
    if (-not ($ht.Keys -contains $object.Color)) {
        $ht[$object.Color] = @()
    }
    $ht[$object.Color] += $object.Number
}

$ht.GetEnumerator() | 
    Select-Object @{Name="Color";Expression={$_.Key}}, @{Name="Number";Expression={$_.Value}}
```

Which will output the following:

```
Color Number
----- ------
Red   {1, 2, 3, 4}
Blue  {5, 6}
Green {7, 8, 9}
```