# Remove text from powershell ouput

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-cmdlet, get-wmiobject

I have this command:

```
Get-WmiObject win32_service |
  ? {$_.Name -like '*Front*'} |
    ? {$_.PathName -like '*logdir*'} |
      select Name, PathName
```

Its ouput is like:

```
Frontapp (Frontapp1) D:\Application\Frontapp\Frontapp.exe -service  -dbType mssql -ORBSvcConf D:\Frontapp83\Frontapp\svc.conf -connections 5 -connectionPoolSize 64 -logdir D:\Frontapp\log1

Frontapp (Frontapp0) D:\Frontapp83\Frontapp\Frontapp.exe -service  -dbType ora -ORBSvcConf D:\Frontapp83\Frontapp\svc.conf -connections 35 -connectionPoolSize 64 -logdir D:\Frontapp\log0
```

How can I remove information from the output, just to obtain the -logdir path.

The output needed:

```
Frontapp (Frontapp1) D:\Frontapp\log1

Frontapp (Frontapp0) D:\Frontapp\log0
```

Comment: As an aside: The CIM cmdlets (e.g., `Get-CimInstance`) superseded the WMI cmdlets (e.g., `Get-WmiObject`) in PowerShell v3 (released in September 2012). Therefore, the WMI cmdlets should be avoided, not least because PowerShell [Core] (version 6 and above), where all future effort will go, doesn't even _have_ them anymore. For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508009/45375).

Answer (score 3):

Use a [calculated property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39861920/45375):

```
Get-WmiObject win32_service |
  ? { $_.Name -like '*Front*' -and $_.PathName -like '*logdir*' } |
    select Name, @{ n='LogDir'; e={ $_.PathName -replace '^.+logdir\s+' } }
```

Answer (score 1):

`Split-Path` can be helpful here...

```
Get-WmiObject win32_service |
? {$_.Name -like '*Front*'} |
? {$_.PathName -like '*logdir*'} |
Select Name, @{N="PathName";E={Split-Path $_.PathName}}
```