# PowerShell: Sorting Within Hashtable Value Collections

Tags: powershell, hashtable, sort-object

I have a test input csv file, as follows:

```
ID;Product;Price;Discount;Level
1;Alpha;23.00;0.03;A
2;Bravo;17.00;0.01;A
3;Charlie;11.00;0.05;A
4;Delta;17.00;0.05;A
5;Echo;29.00;0.07;A
6;Foxtrot;11.00;0.01;A
7;Golf;11.00;0.01;A
1;Hotel;53.00;0.11;B
2;India;53.00;0.13;B
3;Juliet;61.00;0.11;B
1;Kilo;79.00;0.23;C
2;Lima;89.00;0.23;C
3;Mike;97.00;0.29;C
4;November;83.00;0.17;C
5;Oscar;79.00;0.11;C
```

and I would like to generate the following output file:

```
ID;Product;Price;Discount;Level
1;Alpha;23.00;0.03;A
5;Echo;29.00;0.07;A
2;India;53.00;0.13;B
3;Juliet;61.00;0.11;B
2;Lima;89.00;0.23;C
3;Mike;97.00;0.29;C
```

That is, for each level I want to select the top two rows sorted by price and then discount. For example, for level `B`, I want `Juliet` and `India` not `Juliet` and `Hotel`.

I have the following code snippet which does not quite deliver!

```
$input = '.\TestInput.csv'
$products = @(Import-CSV -Path $input -Delimiter ";")
$levels = $products | 
    Group-Object -Property Level -AsHashTable 

$sales = $levels.GetEnumerator() | 
    Sort-Object -Property @{ Expression = { [int]($_.Price) } ; Descending = $true },
                          @{ Expression = { [int]($_.Discount) } ; Descending = $true } | 
    Select-Object -first 2

$output = '.\TestOutput.csv'
$sales | Export-Csv -Path $output -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Group-Object` directly on the `Import-Csv` output:

```
Import-Csv '.\TestInput.csv' -Delimiter ';' | 
  Group-Object Level | 
    ForEach-Object { 
      $_.Group |
        Sort-Object { [int] $_.Price }, { [int] $_.Discount } |
          Select-Object -Last 2
    } | 
        Export-Csv -Path '.\TestOutput.csv' -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation
```

<sup>Note: In PowerShell [Core] v6+, you could replace `| Select-Object Last 2` with `-Bottom 2`, given that `Sort-Object` now supports `-Top` and `-Bottom` parameters.</sup>

---

As for **what you tried**:

- While `Group-Object` normally sorts the resulting groups by the specified grouping criterion(s) (`Level`, in this case), this sorting is no longer guaranteed if you use `-AsHashtable`, given that hashtable entries are inherently unordered.

  - To prevent that, either use the default output (*no* `-AsHashtable`) - which yields individual group objects - as shown above, or add a final `Sort-Object` call that sorts by `Level`.
- `$levels.GetEnumerator()` sends key-value *pairs* (`System.Collections.DictionaryEntry` instances) through the pipeline, whose `.Key` property is the grouping criterion (`.Level`) and whose `.Value` property is the associated group.

  - However, you should be sending just the entry  *values* - i.e., the group objects - through the pipeline, not key-value pairs; this can be achieved by simply accessing the hashtable's `.Values` property

    - However, since you need to process each group *individually*, to find the maximum values in *each*, you need an intermediate `ForEach-Object` call inside of which to perform the group-specific processing.
- You're using [calculated properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39861920/45375) - hashtable-based dynamic property definitions - to specify the criteria for `Sort-Object`; however, with `Sort-Object` that is never necessary, because you'll never see the *name* of such a property; therefore, using the expression script block *directly* (as shown) above is enough.
- Since your sorting is in *descending* order, `Select-Object -First 2` will show the two highest values, but in *descending* order, whereas your desired output requests them in *ascending order*.

  - To get the latter, sort *ascending*, then select the *last* 2 objects.

To put it all together (but note that the solution at the top is both conceptually simpler and more efficient):

```
$sales = 
  $levels.Values | ForEach-Object { 
      $_ |  # process the group at hand
        Sort-Object -Property { [int] $_.Price }, { [int] $_.Discount } | 
          Select-Object -Last 2
    } | Sort-Object Level
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$sales = ForEach ($Level in $levels.Keys | Sort-Object) { $levels.$Level | Sort-Object -Property  price,discount | Select-Object -last 2 }
```

Comment: Nice, but note that the `Price` and `Discount` properties are _strings_, due to having been loaded from a CSV file, but you'll want to sort them as _numbers_.