# How can I replace a string inside a pipe?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to replace some specific parts of a selected string but am only returning the length property. Here's my code:

```
Get-ChildItem "StartPath/Something/Files" -Recurse -File | Select "FullName | Foreach {$_.FullName -replace "StartPath",""} | Export-Csv "ResultPath.csv"
```

If I omit the `foreach` bit, this works in that it spits out the full path. I'd like to trim the full path as I'm iterating over tons of files. I'm trying to replace a bit of the path in the beginning of the string but my code above just spits out a CSV file with just string lengths.

Looks like:

```
"123"
"12"
"52"
```

and so forth.

The intended result would be a csv file with instead of:

```
StartPath/Something/Files1
StartPath/Something/Files2
```

I'd have

```
Something/Files1
Something/Files2
```

I've tried a number of things and can't seem to figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pass a *string* to `select` / [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Select-Object) (to its positionally implied `-Property` parameter), it must be a *property name*.<sup>[1]</sup>

If you want to *perform open-ended operations and/or produce open-ended output for each input object*, you must use the [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/ForEach-Object) cmdlet:

```
Get-ChildItem "StartPath/Something/Files" -Recurse -File | 
  ForEach-Object { 
    [pscustomobject] @{ FullName = $_.FullName -replace 'StartPath' } 
  } | 
    Export-Csv "ResultPath.csv"
```

Note the use of a `[pscustomobject]` wrapper that defines a `FullName` *property*, so that `Export-Csv` creates a CSV with that property as its (only) column.

If you pipe `[string]` instances *directly* to `Export-Csv`, *their* properties are serialized to the output file - and a `[string]`'s only (public) property is *its length* (`.Length`), which is what you saw.

---

<sup>[1] There's also a way to create properties *dynamically*, using so-called [calculated properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39861920/45375), which are defined via *hash tables*.</sup>