# PowerShell 7.1, How do I Get Aliases from a List of Functions Names

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0, powershell-7.0

I'm fairly new to Powershell so I may be missing something, so hear goes:

Note: I prefix all my functions with my initials  `Function mts_do_something()`

I'm trying to walk through a list of Functions  ( `Get-Command mts_*` ) and get their associated aliases.

However, some of the Functions don't have aliases ( so `Get-Alias -Definition mts_do_something`  ), this command returns an error.  So I walk through the list of aliases and try to match them to the item from the 'GCM'.

Sample Code:

```
Get-Command mts_* | foreach-object -Process { 
    $name = $_.ToString() 
    $aliasName = ""
    Get-Alias -Definition mts_* | ForEach-Object -Process { 
        if($_.Definition -eq $Name) { 
            $aliasName = $_.Name 
        }
    }
    if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($aliasName.ToString().Trim()))
    {
        Write-Host "  " $name.PadRight(30)
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "  " $name.PadRight(30) " --> " $aliasName
    }
}
```

Sample Output:

```
mts_do_something 
mts_my_function       -->   myf
mts_fix_car
mts_walk_dog          -->   wDog
```

Question:   While this code produces the desired output, is there an elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> this command returns an error.

You can simply *ignore* these errors, using the [common `-ErrorAction` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters?view=powershell-7.2#erroraction), which simplifies your approach:

```
Get-Command mts_* | ForEach-Object { Get-Alias -ErrorAction Ignore -Definition $_ }
```

**Caveat**: This won't find aliases of commands from [auto-loading modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Modules#module-auto-loading) that *haven't yet been loaded (imported)* into the current session; note that such modules are *implicitly* loaded the first time you call any of their *non-alias* commands.
Similarly, `Get-Alias` only reports aliases from *currently loaded (imported)* modules, so the caveat also applies to [Scepticalist's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65058159/45375), which additionally has the disadvantage of having to call `Get-Alias` to retrieve and filter *all* aliases *for every input command name*.

Note that [`Get-Alias`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-alias)'s output formatting includes both the alias name and the definition (target command), so that you'll see something like:

```
CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Alias           foo -> mts_foo
Alias           bar -> mts_bar
```

If instead you want a two-column display limited to the alias name and its definition, you can use [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object):

```
Get-Command mts_* |
  ForEach-Object { Get-Alias -ErrorAction Ignore -Definition $_ } |
    Select-Object Name, Definition
```

The advantage of using `Select-Object` is that it outputs *objects* suitable for later *programmatic processing*.

You'll get something like:

```
Name Definition
---- ----------
foo  mts_foo
bar  mts_date
```

However, in order to control the *display* output you can instead use [`Format-Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table), which gives you more control over the formatting - but prevents subsequent processing of the output, given that `Format-*` cmdlets output *formatting instructions* rather than the original *data*.

For instance, the following gets closer to your original output format:

```
Get-Command mts_* |
  ForEach-Object { Get-Alias -ErrorAction Ignore -Definition $_ } |
    Format-Table  Name, { '->' },  Definition -HideTableHeaders
```

The `{ '->' }` [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) is a (simple) example of a [calculated property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39861920/45375), which are typically [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables)-based (`@{ ... }`), and in the case of `Format-Table` even allow you to control the column width via a `width` entry.

You'll get something like:

```
foo  ->     mts_foo
bar  ->     mts_bar
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
Get-Command -Name mts_* | ForEach-Object {
    $CurObj = $_.Name
    $Aliases = Get-Alias | Where-Object { $_.Definition -like $CurObj}
    [pscustomobject]@{Command = $CurObj;Aliases = $Aliases}
}
```