# Combining Powershell Output to Single csv

Tags: powershell

I cobbled together the powershell commands below to export the list of servers which are members of a security group to csv. I have a number of commands which produces its own csv. Instead of having a dozen csv files, I want to produce one csv overall with two columns, server name and the security group it is in. How can this be done?

```
Get-ADGroupMember -identity "SecGrp-123" -server "test.net" | select name | sort-object name | export-csv "SecGrp-123.csv" -NoTypeInformation
Get-ADGroupMember -identity "SecGrp-456" -server "test.net" | select name | sort-object name | export-csv "SecGrp-456.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: You can run the commands one by one and send the output to a single file. In Unix the double-gt-sign (>>) will append, where as a single (>) will overwrite, ie. `cat foo.txt >> bar.txt`.

Comment: @kometen, you cannot simply concatenate multiple CSV files with `>>`, since each file has a header row.

Comment: You'd of course have to omit the header in that case. The utilities head and tail and grep does a nice job doing just that.

Comment: These are Windows Powershell commands being run, not Unix. The important thing I need here though is to capture the security group name in the spreadsheet alongside the server name, i.e. row 1 would have VM001, SecGrp-123; row 2 has VM002; SecGrp-123; row 3 has VM100,SecGrp-456, etc etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're looking for something like this:

```
Write-Output SecGrp-123, SecGrp-456 -PipelineVariable groupName | 
  ForEach-Object {
    Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $_ -Server test.net | Sort-Object Name
  } | 
      Select-Object Name, @{ n='Group'; e={ $groupName } } | 
        Export-Csv out.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Note: The above sorts the servers by name *per group*. If you want to sort by name *across all groups*, move the `Sort-Object Name` call outside the `ForEach-Object` call and place it after the latter as a new pipeline segment.

---

If `Get-ADGroupMember` accepts group-name *strings* as pipeline input (I can't verify this), you can simplify to:

```
Write-Output SecGrp-123, SecGrp-456 -PipelineVariable groupName | 
  Get-ADGroupMember -Server test.net | 
    Sort-Object Name |
      Select-Object Name, @{ n='Group'; e={ $groupName } } | 
        Export-Csv out.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Note: This sorts by server name *across all groups*; to sort *per group*, use `Sort-Object Group, Name`, which will list the groups in sort order too.

---

See also:

- The [common `-PipelineVariable` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#pipelinevariable) (PSv4+; alias `-pv`), which saves a cmdlet's current output object in a variable of the given name for later use in a downstream cmdlet's script block.
- [Calculated properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39861920/45375), the mechanism that is used to define the `Group` property in the [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) call.

Comment: That works really well thanks! I commented out lines 2 and 4 but it produces an empty out.csv file. If I wanted to add a third (& final!) column with the domain name (test.net, dev.net, prod.net) and append the result files together into one, could that be done too?

Comment: Thanks for checking: you cannot just comment out line 4, because then you're missing a `|` after the `Get-ADGroupMember` call, and the `Select-Object` call starts a _new_ pipeline; since that new pipeline then has no input, `Export-Csv` creates an empty file.

Comment: You can simply add another calculated property to the `Select-Object` call, such as `@{ n='Domain'; e={ 'test.net' } }` - but that would hard-code the domain name. Where would the other names come from?

Comment: You can use a single pipeline with multiple commands to create a single output file, using the following idiom: `& { <command1>; <command2>; <command3> } | Export-Csv ...`