# while using arraylist how to display objects in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, azure-powershell, powershell-4.0

```
$result = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
ForEach ($repoElement in $Repo.value)
{
 $repoId = $repoElement.id
 $BranchCreatorUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/xyz/_apis/git/repositories/$repoId/refs?api-version=6.1-preview.1"
 $CreateorInfo = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $BranchCreatorUrl -Method Get -UseDefaultCredential -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)})
 $url1= "https://dev.azure.com/xyz/_apis/policy/configurations?api-version=4.1"
 $response = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url1 -Method Get -UseDefaultCredential -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)})
 
 $obj=[pscustomobject]@{
            RepositoryName = $repoElement.name
            RepositoryId = $repoId
            BranchName = $CreateorInfo.value.name
            PolicyName = $response.value.type.displayname
        }
        $result += $obj
        
}
Write-Output $result


The above code gives an output
```

[image]

**I want to show all the branch name as string and not in the form of object ie this way {..,...,...,..}**

Comment: `$result.BranchName` to see each object's value. `$result[0].BranchName` to see the value for the first object. `$result[0].BranchName -join ','` to see the first object's value as a comma-delimited string rather than a collection. This is all assuming you aren't actually using PowerShell v2 as you have tagged.

Comment: I want to show all the names in the branch object as comma separated string for all the repositories(rows) 
 @AdminOfThings

Comment: `$result.foreach({$_.BranchName -join ','})` will do that

Comment: You probably need to replace BranchName = $CreateorInfo.value.name with  BranchName = $($CreateorInfo.value.name -join ",").

Comment: It works. Thankyou for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is just about for-display formatting, i.e. what is shown in the implicitly table-formatted display output, you can call [`Format-Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table) *explicitly* and use a [calculated column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39861920/45375) to apply custom formatting to the `BranchName` column:

```
# Sample result.
$result = [pscustomobject]@{
  RepositoryName = 'name'
  RepositoryId = 'id'
  BranchName = 'branch1', 'branch2', 'branch3'
  PolicyName = 'policy'
}

# Use explicit Format-Table formatting with custom formatting of the 
# 'BranchName' column.
$result | Format-Table RepositoryName, 
                       RepositoryId, 
                       @{ n='BranchName'; e={ $_.BranchName -join ', ' } },
                       PolicyName
```

The above yields a tabular display whose `BranchName` column doesn't have the enclosing `{ ... }`, which PowerShell uses to indicate that the column value is an *array* (perhaps confusingly, because it looks like a *script block*):

```
RepositoryName RepositoryId BranchName                PolicyName
-------------- ------------ ----------                ----------
name           id           branch1, branch2, branch3 policy
```

Comment: Glad to hear it, @SudarshanSharma; my pleasure.