# Data manipulation\deduplication in powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, scripting, data-manipulation, group-object

Hey I am looking to deduplicate some data and combine columns from a CSV. Can't get my head around how to do it. Here is a sample of the data I am working with:

```
cmmc,stig,descr
AC.1.001,SV-205663r569188_rule,The ability to set access permissions and auditing is critical to maintaining the security and proper access controls of a system. To support this volumes must be formatted using a file system that supports NTFS attributes.
AC.1.001,SV-205667r569188_rule,Inappropriate granting of user rights can provide system administrative and other high-level capabilities.
AC.1.002,SV-205663r569188_rule,The ability to set access permissions and auditing is critical to maintaining the security and proper access controls of a system. To support this volumes must be formatted using a file system that supports NTFS attributes.
AC.1.002,SV-205665r569188_rule,Enterprise Domain Controllers groups on domain controllers.
```

I am pretty close to the data I am looking for but struggling to add the `|<value of 'descr'>` after the item in the second column:

Here's my script:

```
Import-CSV '.\input.csv' | Group-Object 'cmmc' |
    ForEach-Object {
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            cmmc = $_.name
            stig = $_.group.stig -Join '
'
                    }
    } | Export-Csv '.\output.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

The output looks like this (formatted for readability, column names omitted):

```
AC1.001    SV-205663r569188_rule
           SV-205665r569188_rule
AC1.002    SV-205663r569188_rule
           SV-205665r569188_rule
```

But I am looking for this:

```
AC.1.001 SV-205663r569188_rule|The ability to set access permissions and auditing is critical to maintaining the security and proper access controls of a system. To support this volumes must be formatted using a file system that supports NTFS attributes.
         SV-205667r569188_rule|Inappropriate granting of user rights can provide system administrative and other high-level capabilities.
AC.1.002 SV-205663r569188_rule|The ability to set access permissions and auditing is critical to maintaining the security and proper access controls of a system. To support this volumes must be formatted using a file system that supports NTFS attributes.
         SV-205665r569188_rule|Enterprise Domain Controllers groups on domain controllers.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following, which makes use of [calculated properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39861920/45375) in combination with the [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) cmdlet applied to the results from your [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object) call:

```sh
Import-Csv .\input.csv | 
  Group-Object cmmc |
    Select-Object @{ Name = 'cmmc'; e = 'Name' },
      @{ Name = 'stig_descr'; e = { 
          [array] $stigs, [array] $descrs, $i = $_.Group.stig, $_.Group.descr, 0
          $sigs.ForEach( { $stigs[$i], $descrs[$i++] -join '|' }) -join "`n" 
        } 
      } | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding utf8 .\output.csv
```

<sup>Note:

• The `[array]` type constraints for `$stigs` and `$descrs` are needed to handle the case where a group comprises only *one* record, in which case `$_.Group.sig` and `$_.Group.descr`, due to the behavior of [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375), return only a *single string* rater than a *single-element array*; without the `[array]` cast, indexing (e.g. `[$i]`) would then be performed on `[string]` instances, which would return the *a single character at that position* from the string.

• In the `Export-Csv` call, adjust `-Encoding` as needed. BOM-less UTF-8 is now the default in *PowerShell (Core) 7+*, and `-NoTypeInformation` is no longer required there.</sup>

The resulting file has the following content, showing the use of column-internal newlines (which are protected by the value as a whole being enclosed in `"..."`):

```sh
"cmmc","stig_descr"
"AC.1.001","SV-205663r569188_rule|The ability to set access permissions and auditing is critical to maintaining the security and proper access controls of a system. To support this volumes must be formatted using a file system that supports NTFS attributes.
SV-205667r569188_rule|Inappropriate granting of user rights can provide system administrative and other high-level capabilities."
"AC.1.002","SV-205663r569188_rule|The ability to set access permissions and auditing is critical to maintaining the security and proper access controls of a system. To support this volumes must be formatted using a file system that supports NTFS attributes.
SV-205665r569188_rule|Enterprise Domain Controllers groups on domain controllers."
```

---

To visualize that this yields the desired data, you can re-import the resulting file and pipe it to [`Format-Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table) with the `-Wrap` switch:

```sh
PS> Import-Csv .\output.csv | Format-Table -Wrap

cmmc     stig_descr
----     ---------
AC.1.001 SV-205663r569188_rule|The ability to set access permissions and auditing is critical to maintaining the security and proper access controls of a system. To support this volumes must be formatted using a file system that supports NTFS attributes.
         SV-205667r569188_rule|Inappropriate granting of user rights can provide system administrative and other high-level capabilities.
AC.1.002 SV-205663r569188_rule|The ability to set access permissions and auditing is critical to maintaining the security and proper access controls of a system. To support this volumes must be formatted using a file system that supports NTFS attributes.
         SV-205665r569188_rule|Enterprise Domain Controllers groups on domain controllers.
```

Note that `-Wrap` respects the property-internal newlines, but additionally breaks individual lines into multiple ones if they're too wide for the console window.