# How do you list the Scopes of all your installed programs on Windows 10? Preferably through PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell

Is there a way I can check the scope of my installed programs? I would like to know if certain programs are for just the CurrentUser or if they can be used by AllUsers. Preferably via PowerShell, but I guess it doesn't have to be.

Comment: take a look at this script: https://powershell.one/code/5.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To **find all executables in the PATH (located in directories listed in `$env:PATH`) located in directories *outside* the current user's home directory tree**, using the [`Get-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-command) and [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) cmdlets:

```sh
# Finds all executables in $env:PATH that are *not* located in the 
# current user's home-directory tree.
Get-Command -Type Application |
  Where-Object { -not $_.Path.StartsWith($HOME, 'OrdinalIgnoreCase') }
```

To **ask the question for given executable names**, using a [calculated property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39861920/45375):

```
# For the given executable names, outputs [pscustomobject] instances
# containing each executable's full path and a flag that indicates 
# whether the executable's directory is located in the 
# current user's home-directory tree.
Get-Command -Type Application foo, bar | 
  Select-Object Path, 
                @{ Name='CurrentUserOnly'; Expression={ $_.Path.StartsWith($HOME, 'OrdinalIgnoreCase') } }
```

---

If you want to **include executables that you can't invoke *directly* from a shell (whose directories *aren't* in `$env:PATH`), but can be invoked via `start` (`cmd.exe`) / `Start-Process` (PowerShell) / via the GUI's `Run` dialog (<kbd>WinKey-R</kbd>)**, such as `excel.exe`:

```sh
# Finds all executables in $env:PATH *and* those that can be launched
# via cmd /c start / Start-Process, which are *not* located in the 
# current user's home-directory tree.
# Lists full paths only.
@(Get-Command -Type Application).Path +
  (Get-ChildItem 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths').
    ForEach({ if ($val = $_.GetValue('') -replace '"') { $val } }) |
      Where-Object { -not $_.StartsWith($HOME, 'OrdinalIgnoreCase') }
```

---

Note: Unfortunately, [`Get-Package`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/packagemanagement/get-package?view=powershell-7&WT.mc_id=ps-gethelp) `-IncludeWindowsInstaller` is *not* an option, because, while it does list installed applications, it seemingly:

- cannot be combined with `-Scope CurrentUser` or `-Scope AllUsers` in Windows PowerShell; also `-IncludeWindowsInstaller` / `-ProviderName Programs` isn't supported at all in *PowerShell (Core) 7+*, at least by default.
- also doesn't return information about the installed programs' *executable paths*.

Comment: Thanks, @mklement0. Really appreciate the help. This mostly worked, however, I did notice that it didn't get everything. For example, I couldn't get Firefox or Google Chrome to pull up. Might there be a way of getting those to appear?

Comment: @L.King, certain additional applications can be detected, yes - but it depends on whether they've created entries under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths`. Please see my update.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying the get-package's -scope parameter, but that doesn't apply to applications.  Here's another way to get it (Powershell 5.1).  These per user apps tend to be the bane of administrators.

```
get-package | ? fastpackagereference -match hklm # 130 items


get-package | ? fastpackagereference -match hkcu | ft -a

Name                                Version          Source ProviderName
----                                -------          ------ ------------
Cisco Webex Meetings                41.5.4                  Programs
Amazon Kindle                       1.31.0.60170            Programs
f.lux                                                       Programs
Microsoft OneDrive                  21.073.0411.0002        Programs
Slack                               4.16.1                  Programs
Microsoft Teams                     1.4.00.4167             Programs
Microsoft Visual Studio Code (User) 1.55.2                  Programs
```

Comment: Thanks, @js2010. Unfortunately, that only displays packages that have been installed by `PowerShellGet`.