# PowerShell - How do you do math on two columns in a Select-Object Expression?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to come up with a percent column by dividing two columns in a select-object.  This is what I'm using:

```
Get-DbaDbLogSpace -SqlInstance serverName |
  Select-Object ComputerName, InstanceName, SqlInstance, Database, LogSize, 
                LogSpaceUsed, LogSpaceUsedPercent,
                @{Name="PercentFree"; Expression={($_.LogSpaceUsed / $_.LogSize)}} | 
    Format-Table
```

This returns an 'OB' on the expression column (see pic below).  How do I do math with two columns in a Select-Object expression please?

If doing this a different way outside of a Select-Object would be better, I'm open to it.

This is what the data looks like for the above code:
[image]

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operands of your calculation appear to be *strings* with *byte multipliers* (e.g. `38.99 MB`), so you'll have to transform them to *numbers* in order to perform division on them.

Here's a simplified example:

- Note: I'm using [`Invoke-Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression) to transform the strings to numbers, relying on PowerShell's support for byte-multiplier suffixes such as `mb` in number *literals* (e.g., `1mb` - note that there must be no space before the suffix). While [`Invoke-Expression` (`iex`) should generally be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375), it is safe to use if you trust that the relevant property values only ever contain strings such as `'38.99 MB'`.

```
[pscustomobject] @{
  Database     = 'db1'
  LogSize      = '11 MB'
  LogSpaceUsed = '3 MB'
} | 
  Format-Table Database, LogSize, LogSpaceUsed, 
    @{
      Name       = "PercentFree"
      Expression = { 
        '{0:P2}' -f ((Invoke-Expression ($_.LogSpaceUsed -replace ' ')) / 
                    (Invoke-Expression ($_.LogSize -replace ' ')))
      }
    }
```

<sup>Note that I'm passing the properties, including the [calculated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39861920/45375) one directly to `Format-Table` - no need for an intermediary [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) call. Note that the calculated property outputs the percentage as a *formatted string*, using the [`-f` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#format-operator--f), so that the number of decimal places can be controlled.</sup>

Output:

```
Database LogSize LogSpaceUsed PercentFree
-------- ------- ------------ -----------
db1      11 MB   3 MB         27.27%
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @mklement0, this is what works.

```
  Get-DbaDbLogSpace -SQLInstance servername | Format-Table Database, LogSize, LogSpaceUsed, 
    @{
      Name       = "PercentFree"
      Expression = { 
        '{0:P2}' -f ((Invoke-Expression ($_.LogSpaceUsed -replace ' ')) / 
                    (Invoke-Expression ($_.LogSize -replace ' ')))
      }
    }
```