# Powershell Group Paramter - Count over 100 adds value to variable

Tags: powershell, output

I found the below article to help me group a list of IP addresses.

[Using Powershell, how can i count the occurrence of each element in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12640962/using-powershell-how-can-i-count-the-occurrence-of-each-element-in-an-array)

The command I am currently using is:

```
get-content c:\temp\temp3.txt | group
```

This would get the following output:

```
> Count Name                      Group
----- ----                      -----
    3 192.168.1.1             {192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.1}
    3 192.168.1.2             {192.168.1.2, 192.168.1.2, 192.168.1.2}
```

What command can I use to find all IP's with over a count of 5?

I imagine I would need to put my orignal command as a variable like below:

```
$groupedoutput get-content c:\temp\temp3.txt | group
```

Unsure where to go from there. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In full:

```
Get-Content -Path c:\temp\temp3.txt  | 
    Group-Object  -NoElement         | 
    Where-Object  { $_.Count -gt 5 } | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```

In short:

```
gc c:\temp\temp3.txt | group |? count -gt 5 |% Name
```

The -NoElement switch means the groups don't gather up all this stuff: `{192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.1}` , it's not really necessary here but it saves memory if you aren't going to use the grouped items.

Comment: Good job, i prefert 'Select Name ' (i use too SQL i think)