# Find the statistical mode(s) of a dataset in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, statistics

This self-answered question is a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12640962/45375):

How can I determine a given dataset's (array's) [statistical mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(statistics)), i.e. the one value or the set of values that occur most frequently?

For instance, in array `1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5` there are two modes, `2` and `4`, because they are the values occurring most frequently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a combination of `Group-Object`, `Sort-Object`, and a `do ... while` loop:

```bsh
# Sample dataset.
$dataset = 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5

# Group the same numbers and sort the groups by member count, highest counts first.
$groups = $dataset | Group-Object | Sort-Object Count -Descending

# Output only the numbers represented by those groups that have 
# the highest member count.
$i = 0
do { $groups[$i].Group[0] } while ($groups[++$i].Count -eq $groups[0].Count)
```

The above yields `2` and `4`, which are the two modes (values occurring most frequently, twice each in this case), sorted in ascending order (because `Group-Object` sorts by the grouping criterion and `Sort-Object`'s sorting algorithm is stable).

Note: While this solution is conceptually straightforward, performance with large datasets may be a concern; see the bottom section for an optimization that is possible for certain inputs.

**Explanation:**

- [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object) groups all inputs by equality.
- [`Sort-Object -Descending`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object) sorts the resulting groups by member count in descending fashion (most frequently occurring inputs first).
- The `do ... while` statement loops over the sorted groups and outputs the input represented by each as long as the group-member and therefore occurrence count (frequency) is the highest, as implied by the first group's member count.

---

**Better-performing solution, with strings and numbers:**

If the input elements are uniformly *simple numbers or strings* (as opposed to complex objects), an optimization is possible:

- `Group-Object`'s `-NoElement` suppresses collecting the individual inputs in each group.
- Each group's `.Name` property reflects the grouping value, but does so as a *string*, so it must be converted back to its original data type.

```bsh
# Sample dataset.
# Must be composed of all numbers or strings.
$dataset = 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5

# Determine the data type of the elements of the dataset via its first element.
# All elements are assumed to be of the same type.
$type = $dataset[0].GetType()

# Group the same numbers and sort the groups by member count, highest counts first.
$groups = $dataset | Group-Object -NoElement | Sort-Object Count -Descending

# Output only the numbers represented by those groups that have 
# the highest member count.
# -as $type converts the .Name string value back to the original type.
$i = 0
do { $groups[$i].Name -as $type } while ($groups[++$i].Count -eq $groups[0].Count)
```

Comment: I may be wrong about this (and would welcome the correction) but couldn't this be much simpler if you just did a where clause to pull out the mode?  $sorted = $dataset | group-object | sort-object -property count -descending and then ($sorted | ? {$_.Count -eq $sorted[0].Count}).Name

Comment: Thanks, @Ryan - there is indeed potential for improvement: my initial thought that a single pipeline would prevent having to collect all objects in memory, but that logic was faulty, because both grouping and sorting require that anyway. Thus, a two-step approach is feasible, and conceptually simpler. However, a `Where-Object` solution would invariably iterate over _all_ groups, which should be avoided - please see my update, which now uses a `do ... while` loop.